# Boost spirit grammar based string splitting

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

I am using Boost 1.44, The Spirit parser works well for numeric parsing but really is tricky for string parsing. I am trying to parse a string to be split using multiple delimiters: ',' ,';' or ' '. It works well for numbers when I do this (where vect = vector < double >):

```
qi::parse(first,last,double_ >> *(',' >> double_  | ' ' >> double_ | ';' >> double_),
```

vect,space);

However when I modify the grammer for strings using vect = vector< string >,

```
+char_ >> *(',' >> +char_  | ' ' >> +char_ | ';' >> +char_)
```

I get the following error:

```
/usr/include/boost/spirit/home/qi/detail/assign_to.hpp:109:13: error: invalid conversion from ‘char’ to ‘const char*’/usr/include/boost/spirit/home/qi/detail/assign_to.hpp:109:13: error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits,_Alloc>::basic_string(const _CharT*, const _Alloc&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]’
```

I narrowed down the error to being the first +char_ in the grammar syntax which is being taken as a series of chars rather than a string. Is there any way to fix this issue?

Thanks

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7436481/how-to-make-my-split-work-only-on-one-real-line-and-be-capable-to-skeep-quoted-pa/7462539#7462539

Answer (score 7, accepted):

String handling (the way you do it) got a lot easier with more recent versions of Spirit. I'd suggest to use Spirit from Boost V1.47, which got a major rewrite of the attribute handling code.

But even if it compiled the way you want, it wouldn't parse the way you expect. Spirit is inherently greedy, that means that `+char_` will consume whatever is left in your input unconditionally. It seems to be better to have

```
+~char_(", ;") % char_(", ;")
```

i.e. one or more (`+`) characters which are not (`~`) in the set `", ;"` interpersed with exactly one of those characters. The list parser (`%`) exposes a `vector<A>`, where `A` is the attribute of the left hand expression, a `vector<string>` in the case above.

Comment: +1, I hadn't noticed the `~` parser operator before (I still used `char_ - char_(", ;")` instead