# Parse quoted strings with boost::spirit

Tags: c++, parsing, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

I would like to parse a sentence where some strings may be unquoted, 'quoted' or "quoted". The code below almost works - but it fails to match closing quotes. I'm guessing this is because of the qq reference. A modification is commented in the code, the modification reults in "quoted' or 'quoted" also parsing and helps show the original problem is with the closing quote. The code also describes the exact grammar.

To be completely clear: unquoted strings parse. A quoted string like `'hello'` will parse the open quote `'`, all the characters  `hello`, but then fail to parse the final quote `'`.

I made another attempt, similar the begin/end tag matching in the [boost tutorials](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/tutorials/mini_xml___asts_.html), but without success.

```
template <typename Iterator>
struct test_parser : qi::grammar<Iterator, dectest::Test(), ascii::space_type>
{
    test_parser()
        :
    test_parser::base_type(test, "test")
    {
        using qi::fail;
        using qi::on_error;
        using qi::lit;
        using qi::lexeme;
        using ascii::char_;
        using qi::repeat;
        using namespace qi::labels;
        using boost::phoenix::construct;
        using boost::phoenix::at_c;
        using boost::phoenix::push_back;
        using boost::phoenix::val;
        using boost::phoenix::ref;
        using qi::space;

        char qq;          

        arrow = lit("->");

        open_quote = (char_('\'') | char_('"')) [ref(qq) = _1];  // Remember what the opening quote was
        close_quote = lit(val(qq));  // Close must match the open
        // close_quote = (char_('\'') | char_('"')); // Enable this line to get code 'almost' working

        quoted_string = 
            open_quote
            >> +ascii::alnum        
            >> close_quote; 

        unquoted_string %= +ascii::alnum;
        any_string %= (quoted_string | unquoted_string);

        test = 
            unquoted_string             [at_c<0>(_val) = _1] 
            > unquoted_string           [at_c<1>(_val) = _1]   
            > repeat(1,3)[any_string]   [at_c<2>(_val) = _1]
            > arrow
            > any_string                [at_c<3>(_val) = _1] 
            ;

        // .. <snip>set rule names
        on_error<fail>(/* <snip> */);
        // debug rules
    }

    qi::rule<Iterator> arrow;
    qi::rule<Iterator> open_quote;
    qi::rule<Iterator> close_quote;

    qi::rule<Iterator, std::string()> quoted_string;
    qi::rule<Iterator, std::string()> unquoted_string;
    qi::rule<Iterator, std::string()> any_string;     // A quoted or unquoted string

    qi::rule<Iterator, dectest::Test(), ascii::space_type> test;

};


// main()
// This example should fail at the very end 
// (ie not parse "str3' because of the mismatched quote
// However, it fails to parse the closing quote of str1
typedef boost::tuple<string, string, vector<string>, string> DataT;
DataT data;
std::string str("addx001 add 'str1'   \"str2\"       ->  \"str3'");
std::string::const_iterator iter = str.begin();
const std::string::const_iterator end = str.end();
bool r = phrase_parse(iter, end, grammar, boost::spirit::ascii::space, data);
```

For bonus credit: A solution that avoid a local data member (such as `char qq` in above example) would be preferred, but from a practical point of view I'll use anything that works!

Comment: For the record, making `char qq` a member variable of `struct test_parser` fails in exactly the same way.

Comment: Fails in what "same way?" You haven't told us how this one fails (though I can image it is due to the `qq` reference).

Comment: @NicolBolas It was a comment in the code - I've since clarified the question, thank for pointing out. I also suspect the ref(qq), but the downside of boost lambda&co is they are tricky to debug as you can't step through in the traditional sense!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The reference to `qq` becomes dangling after leaving the constructor, so that is indeed a problem.

**[`qi::locals`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/parser_concepts/nonterminal.html#spirit.qi.reference.parser_concepts.nonterminal.locals)** is the *canonical* way to keep local state inside parser expressions. Your other option would be to extend the lifetime of `qq` (by making it a member of the grammar class, e.g.). Lastly, you might be interested in *`inherited attributes`* as well. This mechanism gives you a way to call a rule/grammar with 'parameters' (passing local state around).

> ***NOTE** There are caveats with the use of the kleene operator `+`: it is greedy, and parsing fails if the string is not terminated with the expected quote.*
>
> See another answer I wrote for more complete examples of treating arbitrary contents in (optionally/partially) quoted strings, that allow escaping of quotes inside quoted strings and more things like that:
>
> - [How to make my split work only on one real line and be capable to skip quoted parts of string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7436481/how-to-make-my-split-work-only-on-one-real-line-and-be-capable-to-skeep-quoted-p/7462539#7462539)

I've reduced the grammar to the relevant bit, and included a few test cases:

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/adapted.hpp>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

template <typename Iterator>
struct test_parser : qi::grammar<Iterator, std::string(), qi::space_type, qi::locals<char> >
{
    test_parser() : test_parser::base_type(any_string, "test")
    {
        using namespace qi;

        quoted_string = 
               omit    [ char_("'\"") [_a =_1] ]             
            >> no_skip [ *(char_ - char_(_a))  ]
            >> lit(_a)
        ; 

        any_string = quoted_string | +qi::alnum;
    }

    qi::rule<Iterator, std::string(), qi::space_type, qi::locals<char> > quoted_string, any_string;
};

int main()
{
    test_parser<std::string::const_iterator> grammar;
    const char* strs[] = { "\"str1\"", 
                           "'str2'",
                           "'str3' trailing ok",
                           "'st\"r4' embedded also ok",
                           "str5",
                           "str6'",
                           NULL };

    for (const char** it = strs; *it; ++it)
    {
        const std::string str(*it);
        std::string::const_iterator iter = str.begin();
        std::string::const_iterator end  = str.end();

        std::string data;
        bool r = phrase_parse(iter, end, grammar, qi::space, data);

        if (r)
            std::cout << "Parsed:    " << str << " --> " << data << "\n";
        if (iter!=end)
            std::cout << "Remaining: " << std::string(iter,end) << "\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Parsed:    "str1" --> str1
Parsed:    'str2' --> str2
Parsed:    'str3' trailing ok --> str3
Remaining: trailing ok
Parsed:    'st"r4' embedded also ok --> st"r4
Remaining: embedded also ok
Parsed:    str5 --> str5
Parsed:    str6' --> str6
Remaining: '
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was after.

Would you be able to post a link to any documentation/examples about the locals, it took me a while to notice the `qi::local<char>` in the rule signature, and it would be a good reference for me and anyone else looking at this question.

Comment: @Zero thanks! And, erm **[`qi::locals`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/parser_concepts/nonterminal.html#spirit.qi.reference.parser_concepts.nonterminal.locals)** was a hyperlink in my answer :) - _click it for documentation_

Comment: @Zero For a good sample, I'd refer to the page you linked to in your question, notably here: [One More Take](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/tutorials/mini_xml___asts_.html#spirit.qi.tutorials.mini_xml___asts_.one_more_take)

Comment: Aha, got it - at the bottom of [One More Take](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/tutorials/mini_xml___asts_.html#spirit.qi.tutorials.mini_xml___asts_.one_more_take) they talk about the 'locals' template parameter. Thanks again.

Comment: Slightly improved parsing of string literal (accepting any text within the quotes). Now also with fixed test

Comment: Thanks for the edit - I was battling with the quoted_string rule just yesterday, although the answer was so obvious I prefer to put it down to lack of coffee than lack of intelligence ;)