# boost::spirit::qi Expectation Parser and parser grouping unexpected behaviour

Tags: c++, parsing, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

I'm hoping someone can shine a light through my ignorance of using the `>` and `>>` operators in spirit parsing.

I have a working grammar, where the top-level rule looks like

```
test = identifier >> operationRule >> repeat(1,3)[any_string] >> arrow >> any_string >> conditionRule;
```

It relies on attributes to automatically allocated parsed values to a fusion-adapted struct (ie a boost tuple).

However, I know that once we match the operationRule, we must continue or fail (ie we don't want to allow backtracking to try other rules that begin with `identifier`).

```
test = identifier >> 
           operationRule > repeat(1,3)[any_string] > arrow > any_string > conditionRule;
```

This causes a cryptic compiler error (`'boost::Container' : use of class template requires template argument list`). Futz around a bit and the following compiles:

```
test = identifier >> 
           (operationRule > repeat(1,3)[any_string] > arrow > any_string > conditionRule);
```

but the attribute setting no longer works - my data structure contains garbage after parsing. This can be fixed by adding actions like `[at_c<0>(_val) = _1]`, but that seems a little clunky - as well as making things slower according to the boost docs.

So, my questions are

1. Is it worth preventing back-tracking?
2. Why do I need the grouping operator `()`
3. Does my last example above really stop back-tracking after `operationRule` is matched (I suspect not, it seems that if the entire parser inside the `(...)` fails backtracking will be allowed)?
4. If the answer to the previous question is /no/, how do I construct a rule that allows backtracking if `operation` is /not/ matched, but does not allow backtracking once operation /is/ matched?
5. Why does the grouping operator destroy the attribute grammar - requiring actions?

I realise this is quite a broad question - any hints that point in the right direction will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: A more complete description of my grammar is in a previous question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10289985/parse-quoted-strings-with-boostspirit). I don't think this is relevant to the question, which is why I didn't put it in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. **Is it worth preventing back-tracking?**

   Absolutely. Preventing back tracking in general is a proven way to improve parser performance.

   - reduce the use of (negative) lookahead (operator !, operator - and some operator &)
   - order branches (operator |, operator ||, operator^ and some operator */-/+) such that the most frequent/likely branch is ordered first, or that the most costly branch is tried last

   Using expectation points (`>`) does not essentially reduce backtracking: *it will just disallow it*. This will enable targeted error messages, prevent useless 'parsing-into-the-unknown'.
2. **Why do I need the grouping `operator ()`**

   I'm not sure. I had a check [using my `what_is_the_attr` helpers from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9404189/detecting-the-parameter-types-in-a-spirit-semantic-action/9405265#9405265)

   - `ident >> op >> repeat(1,3)[any] >> "->" >> any`
     synthesizes attribute:

     ```
     fusion::vector4<string, string, vector<string>, string>
     ```
   - `ident >> op  > repeat(1,3)[any]  > "->"  > any`
     synthesizes  attribute:

     ```
     fusion::vector3<fusion::vector2<string, string>, vector<string>, string>
     ```

   I haven't found the *need* to group subexpressions using parentheses (things compile), but obviously `DataT` needs to be modified to match the changed layout.

   ```
   typedef boost::tuple<
       boost::tuple<std::string, std::string>, 
       std::vector<std::string>, 
       std::string
   > DataT;
   ```

The full code below shows how I'd prefer to do that, using adapted structs.

1. **Does my above example really stop back-tracking after operationRule is matched (I suspect not, it seems that if the entire parser inside the (...) fails backtracking will be allowed)?**

   Absolutely. If the expectation(s) is not met, a `qi::expectation_failure<>` exception is thrown. This by default *aborts* the parse. You could use qi::on_error to `retry`, `fail`, `accept` or `rethrow`. The [MiniXML example has very good examples on using expectation points with `qi::on_error`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/tutorials/mini_xml___error_handling.html#spirit.qi.tutorials.mini_xml___error_handling.on_error)
2. **If the answer to the previous question is /no/,** <strike>how do I construct a rule that allows backtracking if operation is /not/ matched, but does not allow backtracking once operation /is/ matched?</strike>
3. **Why does the grouping operator destroy the attribute grammar - requiring actions?**

   It doesn't destroy the attribute grammar, it just changes the exposed type. So, if you bind an appropriate attribute reference to the rule/grammar, you won't need semantic actions. Now, I feel there should be ways to go without the grouping <strike>, so let me try it (preferrably on your short selfcontained sample).</strike> *And indeed I have found no such need*. I've added a full example to help you see what is happening in my testing, and not using semantic actions.

### Full Code

The full code show 5 scenarios:

- OPTION 1: Original without expectations

  *(no relevant changes)*
- OPTION 2: with expectations

  *Using the modified typedef for DataT (as shown above)*
- OPTION 3: adapted struct, without expectations

  *Using a userdefined struct with BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT*
- OPTION 4: adapted struct, with expectations

  *Modifying the adapted struct from OPTION 3*
- OPTION 5: lookahead hack

  *This one leverages a **'clever' (?) hack**, by making all `>>` into expectations, and detecting the presence of a `operationRule`-match beforehand. This is of course suboptimal, but allows you to keep `DataT` unmodified, and without using semantic actions.*

Obviously, define `OPTION` to the desired value before compiling.

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/karma.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/adapted.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace qi    = boost::spirit::qi; 
namespace karma = boost::spirit::karma; 

#ifndef OPTION
#define OPTION 5
#endif

#if OPTION == 1 || OPTION == 5 // original without expectations (OR lookahead hack)
    typedef boost::tuple<std::string, std::string, std::vector<std::string>, std::string> DataT;
#elif OPTION == 2 // with expectations
    typedef boost::tuple<boost::tuple<std::string, std::string>, std::vector<std::string>, std::string> DataT;
#elif OPTION == 3 // adapted struct, without expectations
    struct DataT
    {
        std::string identifier, operation;
        std::vector<std::string> values;
        std::string destination;
    };

    BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(DataT, (std::string, identifier)(std::string, operation)(std::vector<std::string>, values)(std::string, destination));
#elif OPTION == 4 // adapted struct, with expectations
    struct IdOpT
    {
        std::string identifier, operation;
    };
    struct DataT
    {
        IdOpT idop;
        std::vector<std::string> values;
        std::string destination;
    };

    BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(IdOpT, (std::string, identifier)(std::string, operation));
    BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(DataT, (IdOpT, idop)(std::vector<std::string>, values)(std::string, destination));
#endif

template <typename Iterator>
struct test_parser : qi::grammar<Iterator, DataT(), qi::space_type, qi::locals<char> >
{
    test_parser() : test_parser::base_type(test, "test")
    {
        using namespace qi;

        quoted_string = 
               omit    [ char_("'\"") [_a =_1] ]             
            >> no_skip [ *(char_ - char_(_a))  ]
             > lit(_a); 

        any_string = quoted_string | +qi::alnum;

        identifier = lexeme [ alnum >> *graph ];

        operationRule = string("add") | "sub";
        arrow = "->";

#if OPTION == 1 || OPTION == 3   // without expectations
        test = identifier >> operationRule >> repeat(1,3)[any_string] >> arrow >> any_string;
#elif OPTION == 2 || OPTION == 4 // with expectations
        test = identifier >> operationRule  > repeat(1,3)[any_string]  > arrow  > any_string;
#elif OPTION == 5                // lookahead hack
        test = &(identifier >> operationRule) > identifier > operationRule > repeat(1,3)[any_string] > arrow > any_string;
#endif
    }

    qi::rule<Iterator, qi::space_type/*, qi::locals<char> */> arrow;
    qi::rule<Iterator, std::string(), qi::space_type/*, qi::locals<char> */> operationRule;
    qi::rule<Iterator, std::string(), qi::space_type/*, qi::locals<char> */> identifier;
    qi::rule<Iterator, std::string(), qi::space_type, qi::locals<char> > quoted_string, any_string;
    qi::rule<Iterator, DataT(),       qi::space_type, qi::locals<char> > test;
};

int main()
{
    std::string str("addx001 add 'str1'   \"str2\"       ->  \"str3\"");
    test_parser<std::string::const_iterator> grammar;
    std::string::const_iterator iter = str.begin();
    std::string::const_iterator end  = str.end();

    DataT data;
    bool r = phrase_parse(iter, end, grammar, qi::space, data);

    if (r)
    {
        using namespace karma;
        std::cout << "OPTION " << OPTION << ": " << str << " --> ";
#if OPTION == 1 || OPTION == 3 || OPTION == 5 // without expectations (OR lookahead hack)
        std::cout << format(delimit[auto_ << auto_ << '[' << auto_ << ']' << " --> " << auto_], data) << "\n";
#elif OPTION == 2 || OPTION == 4 // with expectations
        std::cout << format(delimit[auto_ << '[' << auto_ << ']' << " --> " << auto_], data) << "\n";
#endif
    }
    if (iter!=end)
        std::cout << "Remaining: " << std::string(iter,end) << "\n";
}
```

Output for all OPTIONS:

```
for a in 1 2 3 4 5; do g++ -DOPTION=$a -I ~/custom/boost/ test.cpp -o test$a && ./test$a; done
OPTION 1: addx001 add 'str1'   "str2"       ->  "str3" --> addx001 add [ str1 str2 ]  -->  str3 
OPTION 2: addx001 add 'str1'   "str2"       ->  "str3" --> addx001 add [ str1 str2 ]  -->  str3 
OPTION 3: addx001 add 'str1'   "str2"       ->  "str3" --> addx001 add [ str1 str2 ]  -->  str3 
OPTION 4: addx001 add 'str1'   "str2"       ->  "str3" --> addx001 add [ str1 str2 ]  -->  str3 
OPTION 5: addx001 add 'str1'   "str2"       ->  "str3" --> addx001 add [ str1 str2 ]  -->  str3
```

Comment: Hello again @sehe! I will work on putting together a short example - it will probably take 24 hours. Regarding point 3, I'm not sure you get my meaning. I was wondering if `a >> (b > c > d)` isn't equivalent to `a >> z` with `z = b > c > d` and if so, does this mean that if `z` fails *or* (b > c > d)` fails backtracking is allowed?  The subtle point being that if `d` fails, then `(b > c > d)` has failed, meaning we can backtrack even though `b` passed, which is not the desired effect. At any rate, a smaller example will let me experiment a bit more freely, and maybe find some answers myself!

Comment: @Zero: regarding your comment, if d fails, an exception is thrown. That should clear up the confusion, as to what will happen (assuming no special `on_error` handling) :)

Comment: @Zero: regarding the sample, I think I pretty comprehensively covered the options now, including full sample with no less than **5 different options** of how to handle the attributes/expectations. You might be interested in my **lookahead hack** (option 5), which in essence let's you have your cake and eat it, too