# Spirit Qi attribute propagation issue with single-member struct

Tags: c++, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi, boost-fusion

I have an compilation issue with Spirit Qi where it complains that *value_type* is not a member of *identifier*. For some reason, Qi's attribute system considers identifier to be a container type, and tries to enumerate it's value type.

This is a similar issue as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10378970/boostspiritqi-expectation-parser-and-parser-grouping-unexpected-behaviour), however, I believe the cause is the single member struct and **may** be related to this [bug](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCgQFjAA&url=http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/container-hpp-111-error-C2039-value-type-is-not-a-member-of-td3352328.html&ei=Ubd6UuuqI4emtAap_IHoBw&usg=AFQjCNFxcY30N69hWDh_4_W_kKuKh1cEuQ&bvm=bv.56146854,d.Yms).

```
#include <string>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/adapt_struct.hpp>

using namespace boost::spirit::qi; 

struct identifier
{
    std::wstring name;
};

struct problem
{
    identifier _1;
    identifier _2;
    identifier _3;
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(
    identifier,
    (std::wstring, name)
)

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(
    problem,
    (identifier, _1)
    (identifier, _2)
    (identifier, _3)
)



int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    rule<std::wstring::const_iterator, identifier()> gr_identifier = eps >> raw[lexeme[(alpha | '_') >> *(alnum | '_')]];

    // Ok, compiles
    /*rule<std::wstring::const_iterator, problem()> gr_problem =       gr_identifier
                                                                  >> gr_identifier
                                                                  >> '('
                                                                  >>   gr_identifier
                                                                  >>   ')';*/
    // Fails
    rule<std::wstring::const_iterator, problem()> gr_problem =       gr_identifier
                                                                  >> gr_identifier
                                                                  >> '('
                                                                  >   gr_identifier
                                                                  >   ')';

    std::wstring input = L"foo goo(hoo)";
    /*bool dummy = phrase_parse(
            input.begin(), input.end(), 
            gr_problem,
            space);*/

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Intriguingly, this only occurs when using expectation parser (see definition 2 in the example). Definition 1, using only the sequence parser, compiles (and executes) properly.

Does anybody know the proper solution to this?

Please also check out the [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a020eb1e3d6df836)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is a quite infamous edge-case in Spirit. The problem is, special-case handling of *single-element Fusion Sequences* in Spirit breaks some abstractions.

The usual workaround is to adapt the exposed-attribute side to be less-trivial:

```
rule<It, single_member_struct()> r = eps >> XXX; 
// the `eps` is there to break the spell
```

However, here that won't work, because your `(a > XXX > b)` subexpression results in another `vector1<decltype(member_type)>` and this time, no amount of smart parenthesizing or `eps`-ing will save you.<sup>[1]</sup>

To cut the long story short, I have three workarounds:

---

#### 1. #define KEEP_STRING_WORKAROUND

**See it [Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/89a98a12d29530ee)**

In which you'll simply allow `gr_identifier` to return a `std::wstring`<sup>[2]</sup>:

```
rule<It, std::string()> gr_identifier = 
    (alpha | '_') >> *(alnum | '_');
```

This effectively just postpones the *magic* attribute transformation that uses the Fusion adaptation if `identifier`, and thereby breaks the spell:

```
rule<It, problem(), qi::space_type> gr_problem = 
       gr_identifier
    >> gr_identifier
    >> ('(' > gr_identifier > ')')
    ;
```

Just works. I think this is probably the least intrusive workaround

---

#### 2. #define DUMMY_WORKAROUND

**See it [Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ebac0602533a73f6)**

Whereby you unjinx the magix by ... making the `identifier` struct not fusion adapted to a single-element fusion sequence. Yes. This involves the ***EvilHack™*** of adding a dummy field. To minimize confusion, lets' make it `qi::unused_type` though:

```
struct identifier
{
    std::string    name;
    qi::unused_type dummy;
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(
    identifier,
    (std::string,    name)
    (qi::unused_type, dummy)
)
```

And now:

```
rule<It, identifier()> gr_identifier = 
    (alpha | '_') >> *(alnum | '_') >> attr(42);   // that's hacky
```

Works

---

#### 3. #define NO_ADAPT_WORKAROUND

**See it [Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c0df5ed1bc7fee6c)**

The final workaround might be the most obvious: don't adapt the struct as a fusion sequence in the first place, and profit:

```
struct identifier
{
    std::string name;

    identifier() = default;

    explicit identifier(std::string name) 
        : name(std::move(name))
    {}
};
```

Note that to allow attribute propagation, now you will need suitable *conversion constructors* to be present. Also, the default constructor is required for exposed attributes in Spirit.

Now,

```
rule<It, identifier()> gr_identifier = 
    as_string [ (alpha | '_') >> *(alnum | '_') ]; // cleaner... but no fusion
```

works. This might be more intuitive if you didn't need Fusion of the type for other purposes.

> Note: *this variant could well be the most efficient in compile-time*

## Summary

I think for your code, there are 2 perfectly viable workarounds (#1 and #3), and one less-than-stellar (the one with the dummy field), but I included it for documentary purposes.

### Full Code

For future reference

```
#define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG
#include <string>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/adapt_struct.hpp>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

//////////////////////////////////////////
// Select workaround to demonstrate
#define KEEP_STRING_WORKAROUND
// #define DUMMY_WORKAROUND™
// #define NO_ADAPT_WORKAROUND
//////////////////////////////////////////

#if defined(KEEP_STRING_WORKAROUND)
    struct identifier
    {
        std::string    name;
    };

    BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(
        identifier,
        (std::string,    name)
    )
#elif defined(DUMMY_WORKAROUND)
    struct identifier
    {
        std::string    name;
        qi::unused_type dummy;
    };

    BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(
        identifier,
        (std::string,    name)
        (qi::unused_type, dummy)
    )
#elif defined(NO_ADAPT_WORKAROUND)
    struct identifier
    {
        std::string name;

        identifier() = default;

        explicit identifier(std::string name) 
            : name(std::move(name))
        {}
    };
#endif

struct problem
{
    identifier _1;
    identifier _2;
    identifier _3;
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(
    problem,
    (identifier, _1)
    (identifier, _2)
    (identifier, _3)
)

//////////////////////////////////////////
// For BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG only:
static inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, identifier const& id) {
    return os << id.name;
}
//////////////////////////////////////////

int main()
{
    using namespace qi;
    typedef std::string::const_iterator It;
#if defined(KEEP_STRING_WORKAROUND)
    rule<It, std::string()> gr_identifier = 
        (alpha | '_') >> *(alnum | '_');
#elif defined(DUMMY_WORKAROUND)
    rule<It, identifier()> gr_identifier = 
        (alpha | '_') >> *(alnum | '_') >> attr(42);   // that's hacky
#elif defined(NO_ADAPT_WORKAROUND)
    rule<It, identifier()> gr_identifier = 
        as_string [ (alpha | '_') >> *(alnum | '_') ]; // cleaner... but no fusion
#endif

    rule<It, problem(), qi::space_type> gr_problem = 
           gr_identifier
        >> gr_identifier
        >> ('(' > gr_identifier > ')')
        ;

    std::string input = "foo goo(hoo)";

    BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES((gr_problem)(gr_identifier));

    It f(begin(input)), l(end(input));
    bool dummy = phrase_parse(f, l, gr_problem, qi::space);

    return dummy? 0 : 255;
}
```

---

<sup>[1]</sup> Believe me, I tried, even while inserting `qi::unused_type` "fake" attributes, and/or using `attr_cast<>` or helper rules to coerce the type of the subexpression.

<sup>[2]</sup> For demo purposes, I used `std::string` because I believe it mixes better with BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG

Comment: But what to do with single-fielded class, which field is a container? Say `struct rvalue_list : tagged { std::deque< rvalue > rvalues_ };`. Can I declare and define the c-tor like `template< typename Iterator > rvalue_list::rvalue_list(Iterator const _first, Iterator const _last) : rvalues_(_first, _last) { ; }`?

Comment: @Dukales no? You'd make the constructor accept the exposed attributes. Anyways, here's the direct approach: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d81411f836f7f97c - The alternative is to use custom `traits` to assign to your single-fielded class, which is then effectively a container: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e455a29ade08042b

Comment: Seems like you have answered almost every boost related (IIRC at least spirit) question I had and will have. Greetings from the year 2018.

Comment: How would the reverse i.e. karma way of NO_ADAPT_WORKAROUND look like? I couldn't figure it out with boost::spirit::karma::as, I guess because I would have to add a T/identifier constructor to std::vector<U/std::string> right? My current workaround is boost::spirit::karma::attr_cast with a coustom boost::spirit::traits::transform_attribute<T, std::vector<u>>{static std::vector<U> pre (const &T) function

Comment: @Superlokkus I find that hard to answer without concrete code. Mind you, I practically don't use Karma. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32579406/using-boostkarma-to-format-latitude-longitude-strings/32596517#32596517 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46838958/boost-karma-generator-for-composition-of-classes/46841145#46841145 (both answers in both cases), or simply search [Lounge<C++>](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10/loungec)