# Compiler error when adapting struct with BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit, boost-fusion

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/adapt_struct.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/io.hpp>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;


struct VectorWrapper
{
    std::vector<std::string> data;
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(
    VectorWrapper,
    (std::vector<std::string>, data)
)

int main ()
{
    std::string input("aa aa aa");
    std::string::iterator strbegin = input.begin();

    qi::rule<std::string::iterator, VectorWrapper(), qi::space_type > testRule = 
        +(qi::string("aa"));

    VectorWrapper result;
    bool ok = qi::phrase_parse(
            strbegin, 
            input.end(),
            testRule,
            qi::space,                  
            result);                               

    if (ok && strbegin == input.end()) {
        std::cout << result.data.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < result.data.size(); ++i) {
            std::cout << result.data[i] << " ";
        }
    } else {
        std::cout << "fail" << std::endl;
        std::cout << std::string(strbegin, input.end()) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

I need help to find out problem in this code. Compiler complains about `type` in `VectorWrapper` struct but shouldn't `BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT` add it?

After adding dummy field ([from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19823413/spirit-qi-attribute-propagation-issue-with-single-member-struct))I am getting the same error:

```
struct VectorWrapper
{
    std::vector<std::string> data;
    qi::unused_type dummy;
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(
    VectorWrapper,
    (std::vector<std::string>, data)
    (qi::unused_type, dummy)
)
```

The error message:

```
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/spirit/home/support/string_traits.hpp:16:0,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/spirit/home/support/nonterminal/expand_arg.hpp:20,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/spirit/home/support/context.hpp:18,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/spirit/home/qi/domain.hpp:18,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/spirit/home/qi/meta_compiler.hpp:15,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/spirit/home/qi/action/action.hpp:14,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/spirit/home/qi/action.hpp:14,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/spirit/home/qi.hpp:14,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp:16,
                 from main.cpp:4:
/usr/local/include/boost/spirit/home/support/container.hpp: In instantiation of ‘boost::spirit::traits::container_value<VectorWrapper, void>’:
/usr/local/include/boost/spirit/home/qi/detail/pass_container.hpp:296:66:   instantiated from ‘bool boost::spirit::qi::detail::pass_container<F, Attr, Sequence>::dispatch_attribute(const Component&, mpl_::true_) const [with Component = boost::spirit::qi::literal_string<const char (&)[3], false>, F = boost::spirit::qi::detail::fail_function<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char> >, boost::spirit::context<boost::fusion::cons<VectorWrapper&, boost::fusion::nil>, boost::fusion::vector0<> >, boost::spirit::qi::char_class<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard> > >, Attr = VectorWrapper, Sequence = mpl_::bool_<false>, mpl_::true_ = mpl_::bool_<true>]’
/usr/local/include/boost/spirit/home/qi/detail/pass_container.hpp:331:61:   instantiated from ‘bool boost::spirit::qi::detail::pass_container<F, Attr, Sequence>::operator()(const Component&) const [with Component = boost::spirit::qi::literal_string<const char (&)[3], false>, F = boost::spirit::qi::detail::fail_function<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char> >, boost::spirit::context<boost::fusion::cons<VectorWrapper&, boost::fusion::nil>, boost::fusion::vector0<> >, boost::spirit::qi::char_class<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard> > >, Attr = VectorWrapper, Sequence = mpl_::bool_<false>]’
/usr/local/include/boost/spirit/home/qi/operator/plus.hpp:63:13:   instantiated from ‘bool boost::spirit::qi::plus<Subject>::parse_container(F) const [with F = boost::spirit::qi::detail::pass_container<boost::spirit::qi::detail::fail_function<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char> >, boost::spirit::context<boost::fusion::cons<VectorWrapper&, boost::fusion::nil>, boost::fusion::vector0<> >, boost::spirit::qi::char_class<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard> > >, VectorWrapper, mpl_::bool_<false> >, Subject = boost::spirit::qi::literal_string<const char (&)[3], false>]’
/usr/local/include/boost/spirit/home/qi/operator/plus.hpp:85:13:   instantiated from ‘bool boost::spirit::qi::plus<Subject>::parse(Iterator&, const Iterator&, Context&, const Skipper&, Attribute&) const [with Iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char> >, Context = boost::spirit::context<boost::fusion::cons<VectorWrapper&, boost::fusion::nil>, boost::fusion::vector0<> >, Skipper = boost::spirit::qi::char_class<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard> >, Attribute = VectorWrapper, Subject = boost::spirit::qi::literal_string<const char (&)[3], false>]’
/usr/local/include/boost/spirit/home/qi/nonterminal/detail/parser_binder.hpp:43:54:   instantiated from ‘bool boost::spirit::qi::detail::parser_binder<Parser, Auto>::call(Iterator&, const Iterator&, Context&, const Skipper&, mpl_::false_) const [with Iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char> >, Skipper = boost::spirit::qi::char_class<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard> >, Context = boost::spirit::context<boost::fusion::cons<VectorWrapper&, boost::fusion::nil>, boost::fusion::vector0<> >, Parser = boost::spirit::qi::plus<boost::spirit::qi::literal_string<const char (&)[3], false> >, Auto = mpl_::bool_<false>, mpl_::false_ = mpl_::bool_<false>]’
/usr/local/include/boost/spirit/home/qi/nonterminal/detail/parser_binder.hpp:53:67:   [ skipping 3 instantiation contexts ]
/usr/local/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:722:7:   instantiated from ‘boost::function4<R, T1, T2, T3, T4>::function4(Functor, typename boost::enable_if_c<boost::type_traits::ice_not<boost::is_integral<Functor>::value>::value, int>::type) [with Functor = boost::spirit::qi::detail::parser_binder<boost::spirit::qi::plus<boost::spirit::qi::literal_string<const char (&)[3], false> >, mpl_::bool_<false> >, R = bool, T0 = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char> >&, T1 = const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char> >&, T2 = boost::spirit::context<boost::fusion::cons<VectorWrapper&, boost::fusion::nil>, boost::fusion::vector0<> >&, T3 = const boost::spirit::qi::char_class<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard> >&, typename boost::enable_if_c<boost::type_traits::ice_not<boost::is_integral<Functor>::value>::value, int>::type = int]’
/usr/local/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:1069:16:   instantiated from ‘boost::function<R(T0, T1, T2, T3)>::function(Functor, typename boost::enable_if_c<boost::type_traits::ice_not<boost::is_integral<Functor>::value>::value, int>::type) [with Functor = boost::spirit::qi::detail::parser_binder<boost::spirit::qi::plus<boost::spirit::qi::literal_string<const char (&)[3], false> >, mpl_::bool_<false> >, R = bool, T0 = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char> >&, T1 = const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char> >&, T2 = boost::spirit::context<boost::fusion::cons<VectorWrapper&, boost::fusion::nil>, boost::fusion::vector0<> >&, T3 = const boost::spirit::qi::char_class<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard> >&, typename boost::enable_if_c<boost::type_traits::ice_not<boost::is_integral<Functor>::value>::value, int>::type = int]’
/usr/local/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:1124:5:   instantiated from ‘typename boost::enable_if_c<boost::type_traits::ice_not<boost::is_integral<Functor>::value>::value, boost::function<R(T0, T1, T2, T3)>&>::type boost::function<R(T0, T1, T2, T3)>::operator=(Functor) [with Functor = boost::spirit::qi::detail::parser_binder<boost::spirit::qi::plus<boost::spirit::qi::literal_string<const char (&)[3], false> >, mpl_::bool_<false> >, R = bool, T0 = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char> >&, T1 = const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char> >&, T2 = boost::spirit::context<boost::fusion::cons<VectorWrapper&, boost::fusion::nil>, boost::fusion::vector0<> >&, T3 = const boost::spirit::qi::char_class<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard> >&, typename boost::enable_if_c<boost::type_traits::ice_not<boost::is_integral<Functor>::value>::value, boost::function<R(T0, T1, T2, T3)>&>::type = boost::function<bool(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char> >&, const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char> >&, boost::spirit::context<boost::fusion::cons<VectorWrapper&, boost::fusion::nil>, boost::fusion::vector0<> >&, const boost::spirit::qi::char_class<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard> >&)>&]’
/usr/local/include/boost/spirit/home/qi/nonterminal/rule.hpp:182:13:   instantiated from ‘static void boost::spirit::qi::rule<Iterator, T1, T2, T3, T4>::define(boost::spirit::qi::rule<Iterator, T1, T2, T3, T4>&, const Expr&, mpl_::true_) [with Auto = mpl_::bool_<false>, Expr = boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::unary_plus, boost::proto::argsns_::list1<const boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::spirit::terminal_ex<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::string, boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard>, boost::fusion::vector1<const char (&)[3]> > >, 0l>&>, 1l>, Iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char> >, T1 = VectorWrapper(), T2 = boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard> >, 0l>, T3 = boost::spirit::unused_type, T4 = boost::spirit::unused_type, boost::spirit::qi::rule<Iterator, T1, T2, T3, T4> = boost::spirit::qi::rule<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char> >, VectorWrapper(), boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard> >, 0l> >, mpl_::true_ = mpl_::bool_<true>]’
/usr/local/include/boost/spirit/home/qi/nonterminal/rule.hpp:191:13:   instantiated from ‘boost::spirit::qi::rule<Iterator, T1, T2, T3, T4>::rule(const Expr&, const string&) [with Expr = boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::unary_plus, boost::proto::argsns_::list1<const boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::spirit::terminal_ex<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::string, boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard>, boost::fusion::vector1<const char (&)[3]> > >, 0l>&>, 1l>, Iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char> >, T1 = VectorWrapper(), T2 = boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard> >, 0l>, T3 = boost::spirit::unused_type, T4 = boost::spirit::unused_type, std::string = std::basic_string<char>]’
main.cpp:27:27:   instantiated from here
/usr/local/include/boost/spirit/home/support/container.hpp:116:12: error: no type named ‘value_type’ in ‘struct VectorWrapper’
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/spirit/home/qi/operator/kleene.hpp:20:0,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/spirit/home/qi/directive/repeat.hpp:18,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/spirit/home/qi/directive.hpp:23,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/spirit/home/qi.hpp:19,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp:16,
                 from main.cpp:4:
/usr/local/include/boost/spirit/home/qi/detail/pass_container.hpp: In member function ‘bool boost::spirit::qi::detail::pass_container<F, Attr, Sequence>::dispatch_attribute(const Component&, mpl_::true_) const [with Component = boost::spirit::qi::literal_string<const char (&)[3], false>, F = boost::spirit::qi::detail::fail_function<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char> >, boost::spirit::context<boost::fusion::cons<VectorWrapper&, boost::fusion::nil>, boost::fusion::vector0<> >, boost::spirit::qi::char_class<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard> > >, Attr = VectorWrapper, Sequence = mpl_::bool_<false>, mpl_::true_ = mpl_::bool_<true>]’:
/usr/local/include/boost/spirit/home/qi/detail/pass_container.hpp:331:61:   instantiated from ‘bool boost::spirit::qi::detail::pass_container<F, Attr, Sequence>::operator()(const Component&) const [with Component = boost::spirit::qi::literal_string<const char (&)[3], false>, F = boost::spirit::qi::detail::fail_function<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char> >, boost::spirit::context<boost::fusion::cons<VectorWrapper&, boost::fusion::nil>, boost::fusion::vector0<> >, boost::spirit::qi::char_class<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard> > >, Attr = VectorWrapper, Sequence = mpl_::bool_<false>]’
/usr/local/include/boost/spirit/home/qi/operator/plus.hpp:63:13:   instantiated from ‘bool boost::spirit::qi::plus<Subject>::parse_container(F) const [with F = boost::spirit::qi::detail::pass_container<boost::spirit::qi::detail::fail_function<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char> >, boost::spirit::context<boost::fusion::cons<VectorWrapper&, boost::fusion::nil>, boost::fusion::vector0<> >, boost::spirit::qi::char_class<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard> > >, VectorWrapper, mpl_::bool_<false> >, Subject = boost::spirit::qi::literal_string<const char (&)[3], false>]’
/usr/local/include/boost/spirit/home/qi/operator/plus.hpp:85:13:   instantiated from ‘bool boost::spirit::qi::plus<Subject>::parse(Iterator&, const Iterator&, Context&, const Skipper&, Attribute&) const [with Iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char> >, Context = boost::spirit::context<boost::fusion::cons<VectorWrapper&, boost::fusion::nil>, boost::fusion::vector0<> >, Skipper = boost::spirit::qi::char_class<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard> >, Attribute = VectorWrapper, Subject = boost::spirit::qi::literal_string<const char (&)[3], false>]’
/usr/local/include/boost/spirit/home/qi/nonterminal/detail/parser_binder.hpp:43:54:   instantiated from ‘bool boost::spirit::qi::detail::parser_binder<Parser, Auto>::call(Iterator&, const Iterator&, Context&, const Skipper&, mpl_::false_) const [with Iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char> >, Skipper = boost::spirit::qi::char_class<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard> >, Context = boost::spirit::context<boost::fusion::cons<VectorWrapper&, boost::fusion::nil>, boost::fusion::vector0<> >, Parser = boost::spirit::qi::plus<boost::spirit::qi::literal_string<const char (&)[3], false> >, Auto = mpl_::bool_<false>, mpl_::false_ = mpl_::bool_<false>]’
/usr/local/include/boost/spirit/home/qi/nonterminal/detail/parser_binder.hpp:53:67:   instantiated from ‘bool boost::spirit::qi::detail::parser_binder<Parser, Auto>::operator()(Iterator&, const Iterator&, Context&, const Skipper&) const [with Iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char> >, Skipper = boost::spirit::qi::char_class<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard> >, Context = boost::spirit::context<boost::fusion::cons<VectorWrapper&, boost::fusion::nil>, boost::fusion::vector0<> >, Parser = boost::spirit::qi::plus<boost::spirit::qi::literal_string<const char (&)[3], false> >, Auto = mpl_::bool_<false>]’
/usr/local/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:132:42:   [ skipping 2 instantiation contexts ]
/usr/local/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:722:7:   instantiated from ‘boost::function4<R, T1, T2, T3, T4>::function4(Functor, typename boost::enable_if_c<boost::type_traits::ice_not<boost::is_integral<Functor>::value>::value, int>::type) [with Functor = boost::spirit::qi::detail::parser_binder<boost::spirit::qi::plus<boost::spirit::qi::literal_string<const char (&)[3], false> >, mpl_::bool_<false> >, R = bool, T0 = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char> >&, T1 = const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char> >&, T2 = boost::spirit::context<boost::fusion::cons<VectorWrapper&, boost::fusion::nil>, boost::fusion::vector0<> >&, T3 = const boost::spirit::qi::char_class<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard> >&, typename boost::enable_if_c<boost::type_traits::ice_not<boost::is_integral<Functor>::value>::value, int>::type = int]’
/usr/local/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:1069:16:   instantiated from ‘boost::function<R(T0, T1, T2, T3)>::function(Functor, typename boost::enable_if_c<boost::type_traits::ice_not<boost::is_integral<Functor>::value>::value, int>::type) [with Functor = boost::spirit::qi::detail::parser_binder<boost::spirit::qi::plus<boost::spirit::qi::literal_string<const char (&)[3], false> >, mpl_::bool_<false> >, R = bool, T0 = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char> >&, T1 = const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char> >&, T2 = boost::spirit::context<boost::fusion::cons<VectorWrapper&, boost::fusion::nil>, boost::fusion::vector0<> >&, T3 = const boost::spirit::qi::char_class<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard> >&, typename boost::enable_if_c<boost::type_traits::ice_not<boost::is_integral<Functor>::value>::value, int>::type = int]’
/usr/local/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:1124:5:   instantiated from ‘typename boost::enable_if_c<boost::type_traits::ice_not<boost::is_integral<Functor>::value>::value, boost::function<R(T0, T1, T2, T3)>&>::type boost::function<R(T0, T1, T2, T3)>::operator=(Functor) [with Functor = boost::spirit::qi::detail::parser_binder<boost::spirit::qi::plus<boost::spirit::qi::literal_string<const char (&)[3], false> >, mpl_::bool_<false> >, R = bool, T0 = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char> >&, T1 = const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char> >&, T2 = boost::spirit::context<boost::fusion::cons<VectorWrapper&, boost::fusion::nil>, boost::fusion::vector0<> >&, T3 = const boost::spirit::qi::char_class<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard> >&, typename boost::enable_if_c<boost::type_traits::ice_not<boost::is_integral<Functor>::value>::value, boost::function<R(T0, T1, T2, T3)>&>::type = boost::function<bool(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char> >&, const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char> >&, boost::spirit::context<boost::fusion::cons<VectorWrapper&, boost::fusion::nil>, boost::fusion::vector0<> >&, const boost::spirit::qi::char_class<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard> >&)>&]’
/usr/local/include/boost/spirit/home/qi/nonterminal/rule.hpp:182:13:   instantiated from ‘static void boost::spirit::qi::rule<Iterator, T1, T2, T3, T4>::define(boost::spirit::qi::rule<Iterator, T1, T2, T3, T4>&, const Expr&, mpl_::true_) [with Auto = mpl_::bool_<false>, Expr = boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::unary_plus, boost::proto::argsns_::list1<const boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::spirit::terminal_ex<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::string, boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard>, boost::fusion::vector1<const char (&)[3]> > >, 0l>&>, 1l>, Iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char> >, T1 = VectorWrapper(), T2 = boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard> >, 0l>, T3 = boost::spirit::unused_type, T4 = boost::spirit::unused_type, boost::spirit::qi::rule<Iterator, T1, T2, T3, T4> = boost::spirit::qi::rule<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char> >, VectorWrapper(), boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard> >, 0l> >, mpl_::true_ = mpl_::bool_<true>]’
/usr/local/include/boost/spirit/home/qi/nonterminal/rule.hpp:191:13:   instantiated from ‘boost::spirit::qi::rule<Iterator, T1, T2, T3, T4>::rule(const Expr&, const string&) [with Expr = boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::unary_plus, boost::proto::argsns_::list1<const boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::spirit::terminal_ex<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::string, boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard>, boost::fusion::vector1<const char (&)[3]> > >, 0l>&>, 1l>, Iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char> >, T1 = VectorWrapper(), T2 = boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard> >, 0l>, T3 = boost::spirit::unused_type, T4 = boost::spirit::unused_type, std::string = std::basic_string<char>]’
main.cpp:27:27:   instantiated from here
/usr/local/include/boost/spirit/home/qi/detail/pass_container.hpp:296:66: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘struct boost::spirit::traits::container_value<VectorWrapper, void>’
/usr/local/include/boost/spirit/home/qi/detail/pass_container.hpp:309:15: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘struct boost::spirit::traits::container_value<VectorWrapper, void>’
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

Comment: I used Workaround 2 from that answer but the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to emit an unused type in your rule:

```
qi::rule<std::string::iterator, VectorWrapper(), qi::space_type > testRule = 
    +(qi::string("aa")) >> qi::attr(false);
```

Comment: Where is the qi::unused_type?

Comment: It works on my system with the ``qi::unused_type`` like he wrote in his addentum and emitting the ``qi::attr(false)`` into that unused type.

Comment: I mean, I only see an attribute of type bool added in your code :)

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was clear that I extend his unused type example.

Answer (score 2):

The linked answer should be enough. Since you report trouble still: here's something that works on my compilers:

```
qi::rule<std::string::iterator, VectorWrapper(), qi::space_type > testRule = 
    qi::eps >> +(qi::string("aa"));
```

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2d1b0f2c3d113a7e)**

Comment: Thank you, It worked without adding dummy field