# Boost spirit, why the as<> directive is required? (a.k.a. help me understand the attributes compatibility rules)

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit

This code compiles and works as intended; an input like "{a;b}" is parsed and stored in a custom class

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>

namespace t {
    using std::vector;
    using std::string;
    namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

    struct Block {
        Block() = default;
        Block(vector<string> const& s) : value(s) {}
        vector<string> value;
    };

    template <typename Iterator, typename Skipper=qi::space_type>
    struct G1 : qi::grammar<Iterator, Block(), Skipper> {

        template <typename T>
        using rule = qi::rule<Iterator, T, Skipper>;

        rule<Block()> start;
        G1() : G1::base_type(start, "G1") {
            start = qi::as<vector<string>>()[
                qi::lit('{')
                >> *(+(qi::char_ - ';') >> ';')
                >> '}'
            ];
        }
    };

    Block parse(string const input) {
        G1<string::const_iterator> g;
        Block result;
        phrase_parse(begin(input), end(input), g, qi::standard::space, result);
        return result;
    }
};

int main() {
    using namespace std;
    auto r = t::parse("{a;b;}");
    for (auto& s : r.value) {
        cout << s << endl;
    }
}
```

What I don't understand is why the as<> directive is needed; from what I can infer from the docs the synthesized attribute of the primitive parsers should be already a vector of strings.

I've read [this article](http://boost-spirit.com/home/articles/attribute_handling/attribute-propagation-and-attribute-compatibility/) about attribute propagation and attribute compatibility, but I miss the big picture; what happens when the as directive is (not) used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Otherwise

```
*(+(qi::char_ - ';') >> ';')
```

would just expose a `std::vector<char>` (each kleene-+ would append into the same attribute). As a rule of thumb, kleene-operators always directly pushback into the referenced attribute, which also implies that it expects that attribute to be of container type (the `boost::spirit::traits::container_value<>` trait is used to detect what the attribute of the repeated parser expression should convert to).

In this case, you might find fusion-adaptation with `qi::as_string` more elegant: **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3e6f10222a1a26fb)**

```
struct Block {
    vector<string> value;
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(t::Block,(std::vector<std::string>,value))
// ...

start = 
    qi::lit('{')
    >> *qi::as_string [ +(qi::char_ - ';') >> ';' ]
    >> '}'
;
```

With this, beware of

- [Spirit Qi attribute propagation issue with single-member struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19823413/spirit-qi-attribute-propagation-issue-with-single-member-struct) (a limitation/bug)
- see also: [Detecting the parameter types in a Spirit semantic action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9404189/detecting-the-parameter-types-in-a-spirit-semantic-action)

Comment: You are right!, obviously.

There is a rule of thumb for when use the as<> directive and when a semantic action? Your advice?

Comment: Instead, I'd split out a subrule if you want to help/influence attribute compatibility. I'd only employ semantic actions as a way to optimize or to manage temporary rule state ([Boost Spirit: “Semantic actions are evil”?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8259440/boost-spirit-semantic-actions-are-evil/8259585#8259585))

Comment: Here's the demonstration of that [split subrule](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dc5b5d07097a0556) idea