# Boost::spirit attribute types not collapsing

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

### Problem description

I have a trivial struct, adapted for `boost::fusion`:

```
struct Node
{
  std::string text;
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Node, (std::string, text))
```

I have a grammar with a set of rules:

```
boost::spirit::qi::rule<Iterator, Node()> node_line;
boost::spirit::qi::rule<Iterator, Node()> node;
```

And there is one rule that blows up in my face:

```
node_line %= "  * " >> node;
```

I would expect this to be valid, since the attribute of the literal is `unused`, and `node_line` and `node` have the same attribute type. Instead the compiler complains:

```
/usr/include/boost/spirit/home/support/container.hpp:262:13: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::basic_string<char>::insert(std::basic_string<char>::iterator, const Node&)’
```

I.e. the compiler tries to append a `struct Node` onto a `std::string`. I am utterly confused as to why it would try to do that. Any thoughts?

### Full code

```
#include <boost/config/warning_disable.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/adapt_struct.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>

struct Node
{
  std::string text;
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Node, (std::string, text))

template <typename Iterator>
struct My_parser : boost::spirit::qi::grammar<Iterator, Node()>
{
  My_parser()
    : My_parser::base_type(node_line)
  {
    name %= +boost::spirit::ascii::char_;
    node %= name;

    node_line %= "  * " >> node;
    // node_line %= node;
  }

  boost::spirit::qi::rule<Iterator, std::string()> name;
  boost::spirit::qi::rule<Iterator, Node()> node_line;
  boost::spirit::qi::rule<Iterator, Node()> node;
};

int main()
{
  const std::string input("  * Some text");
  Node parsed;
  My_parser<std::string::const_iterator> my_parser;

  bool r = parse(input.begin(), input.end(), my_parser, parsed);

  if(r)
    std::cout << "Match: " << parsed.text << std::endl;
  else
    std::cout << "No match" << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

### Full error message

```
In file included from /usr/include/boost/spirit/home/support/string_traits.hpp:16:0,
                 from /usr/include/boost/spirit/home/support/nonterminal/expand_arg.hpp:20,
                 from /usr/include/boost/spirit/home/support/context.hpp:15,
                 from /usr/include/boost/spirit/home/qi/domain.hpp:18,
                 from /usr/include/boost/spirit/home/qi/meta_compiler.hpp:15,
                 from /usr/include/boost/spirit/home/qi/action/action.hpp:14,
                 from /usr/include/boost/spirit/home/qi/action.hpp:14,
                 from /usr/include/boost/spirit/home/qi.hpp:14,
                 from /usr/include/boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp:16,
                 from tt.cc:3:
/usr/include/boost/spirit/home/support/container.hpp: In static member function ‘static bool boost::spirit::traits::push_back_container<Container, T, Enable>::call(Container&, const T&) [with Container = std::basic_string<char>, T = Node, Enable = void]’:
/usr/include/boost/spirit/home/support/container.hpp:324:62:   instantiated from ‘bool boost::spirit::traits::push_back(Container&, const T&) [with Container = std::basic_string<char>, T = Node]’
/usr/include/boost/spirit/home/qi/detail/assign_to.hpp:168:13:   instantiated from ‘static void boost::spirit::traits::assign_to_container_from_value<Attribute, T, Enable>::call(const T_&, Attribute&, mpl_::false_, mpl_::false_) [with T_ = Node, Attribute = std::basic_string<char>, T = Node, Enable = void, mpl_::false_ = mpl_::bool_<false>]’
/usr/include/boost/spirit/home/qi/detail/assign_to.hpp:203:13:   instantiated from ‘static void boost::spirit::traits::assign_to_container_from_value<Attribute, T, Enable>::call(const T&, Attribute&) [with Attribute = std::basic_string<char>, T = Node, Enable = void]’
/usr/include/boost/spirit/home/qi/detail/assign_to.hpp:243:13:   instantiated from ‘void boost::spirit::traits::detail::assign_to(const T&, Attribute&, mpl_::true_, mpl_::true_) [with T = Node, Attribute = std::basic_string<char>, mpl_::true_ = mpl_::bool_<true>]’
/usr/include/boost/spirit/home/qi/detail/assign_to.hpp:257:9:   instantiated from ‘void boost::spirit::traits::assign_to(const T&, Attribute&) [with T = Node, Attribute = std::basic_string<char>]’
/usr/include/boost/spirit/home/qi/detail/attributes.hpp:26:13:   [ skipping 12 instantiation contexts ]
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:913:60:   instantiated from ‘void boost::function4<R, T1, T2, T3, T4>::assign_to(Functor) [with Functor = boost::spirit::qi::detail::parser_binder<boost::spirit::qi::sequence<boost::fusion::cons<boost::spirit::qi::literal_string<const char (&)[5], true>, boost::fusion::cons<boost::spirit::qi::reference<const boost::spirit::qi::rule<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char> >, Node(), boost::spirit::unused_type, boost::spirit::unused_type, boost::spirit::unused_type> >, boost::fusion::nil> > >, mpl_::bool_<true> >, R = bool, T0 = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char> >&, T1 = const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char> >&, T2 = boost::spirit::context<boost::fusion::cons<Node&, boost::fusion::nil>, boost::fusion::vector0<> >&, T3 = const boost::spirit::unused_type&]’
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:722:7:   instantiated from ‘boost::function4<R, T1, T2, T3, T4>::function4(Functor, typename boost::enable_if_c<boost::type_traits::ice_not<boost::is_integral<Functor>::value>::value, int>::type) [with Functor = boost::spirit::qi::detail::parser_binder<boost::spirit::qi::sequence<boost::fusion::cons<boost::spirit::qi::literal_string<const char (&)[5], true>, boost::fusion::cons<boost::spirit::qi::reference<const boost::spirit::qi::rule<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char> >, Node(), boost::spirit::unused_type, boost::spirit::unused_type, boost::spirit::unused_type> >, boost::fusion::nil> > >, mpl_::bool_<true> >, R = bool, T0 = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char> >&, T1 = const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char> >&, T2 = boost::spirit::context<boost::fusion::cons<Node&, boost::fusion::nil>, boost::fusion::vector0<> >&, T3 = const boost::spirit::unused_type&, typename boost::enable_if_c<boost::type_traits::ice_not<boost::is_integral<Functor>::value>::value, int>::type = int]’
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:1064:16:   instantiated from ‘boost::function<R(T0, T1, T2, T3)>::function(Functor, typename boost::enable_if_c<boost::type_traits::ice_not<boost::is_integral<Functor>::value>::value, int>::type) [with Functor = boost::spirit::qi::detail::parser_binder<boost::spirit::qi::sequence<boost::fusion::cons<boost::spirit::qi::literal_string<const char (&)[5], true>, boost::fusion::cons<boost::spirit::qi::reference<const boost::spirit::qi::rule<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char> >, Node(), boost::spirit::unused_type, boost::spirit::unused_type, boost::spirit::unused_type> >, boost::fusion::nil> > >, mpl_::bool_<true> >, R = bool, T0 = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char> >&, T1 = const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char> >&, T2 = boost::spirit::context<boost::fusion::cons<Node&, boost::fusion::nil>, boost::fusion::vector0<> >&, T3 = const boost::spirit::unused_type&, typename boost::enable_if_c<boost::type_traits::ice_not<boost::is_integral<Functor>::value>::value, int>::type = int]’
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:1105:5:   instantiated from ‘typename boost::enable_if_c<boost::type_traits::ice_not<boost::is_integral<Functor>::value>::value, boost::function<R(T0, T1, T2, T3)>&>::type boost::function<R(T0, T1, T2, T3)>::operator=(Functor) [with Functor = boost::spirit::qi::detail::parser_binder<boost::spirit::qi::sequence<boost::fusion::cons<boost::spirit::qi::literal_string<const char (&)[5], true>, boost::fusion::cons<boost::spirit::qi::reference<const boost::spirit::qi::rule<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char> >, Node(), boost::spirit::unused_type, boost::spirit::unused_type, boost::spirit::unused_type> >, boost::fusion::nil> > >, mpl_::bool_<true> >, R = bool, T0 = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char> >&, T1 = const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char> >&, T2 = boost::spirit::context<boost::fusion::cons<Node&, boost::fusion::nil>, boost::fusion::vector0<> >&, T3 = const boost::spirit::unused_type&, typename boost::enable_if_c<boost::type_traits::ice_not<boost::is_integral<Functor>::value>::value, boost::function<R(T0, T1, T2, T3)>&>::type = boost::function<bool(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char> >&, const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char> >&, boost::spirit::context<boost::fusion::cons<Node&, boost::fusion::nil>, boost::fusion::vector0<> >&, const boost::spirit::unused_type&)>&]’
/usr/include/boost/spirit/home/qi/nonterminal/rule.hpp:214:13:   instantiated from ‘boost::spirit::qi::rule<Iterator, T1, T2, T3, T4>& boost::spirit::qi::operator%=(boost::spirit::qi::rule<Iterator, T1, T2, T3, T4>&, const Expr&) [with Expr = boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tag::shift_right, boost::proto::argsns_::list2<boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<const char (&)[5]>, 0l>, boost::spirit::qi::rule<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char> >, Node(), boost::spirit::unused_type, boost::spirit::unused_type, boost::spirit::unused_type>&>, 2l>, Iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char> >, T1 = Node(), T2 = boost::spirit::unused_type, T3 = boost::spirit::unused_type, T4 = boost::spirit::unused_type, boost::spirit::qi::rule<Iterator, T1, T2, T3, T4> = boost::spirit::qi::rule<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char> >, Node(), boost::spirit::unused_type, boost::spirit::unused_type, boost::spirit::unused_type>]’
tt.cc:21:5:   instantiated from ‘My_parser<Iterator>::My_parser() [with Iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char> >]’
tt.cc:34:42:   instantiated from here
/usr/include/boost/spirit/home/support/container.hpp:262:13: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::basic_string<char>::insert(std::basic_string<char>::iterator, const Node&)’
/usr/include/boost/spirit/home/support/container.hpp:262:13: note: candidates are:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/basic_string.h:1174:7: note: void std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::insert(std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::iterator, std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::size_type, _CharT) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>, std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char> >, typename _Alloc::rebind<_CharT>::other::pointer = char*, std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::size_type = long unsigned int]
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/basic_string.h:1174:7: note:   candidate expects 3 arguments, 2 provided
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/basic_string.h:1190:9: note: template<class _InputIterator> void std::basic_string::insert(std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::iterator, _InputIterator, _InputIterator) [with _InputIterator = _InputIterator, _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>, std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char> >, typename _Alloc::rebind<_CharT>::other::pointer = char*]
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/basic_string.h:1220:7: note: std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>& std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::insert(std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::size_type, const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>, std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc> = std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::size_type = long unsigned int]
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/basic_string.h:1220:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::basic_string<char>::iterator {aka __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char> >}’ to ‘long unsigned int’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/basic_string.h:1242:7: note: std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>& std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::insert(std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::size_type, const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&, std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::size_type, std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::size_type) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>, std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc> = std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::size_type = long unsigned int]
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/basic_string.h:1242:7: note:   candidate expects 4 arguments, 2 provided
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/basic_string.tcc:361:6: note: std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>& std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::insert(std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::size_type, const _CharT*, std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::size_type) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>, std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::size_type = long unsigned int]
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/basic_string.tcc:361:6: note:   candidate expects 3 arguments, 2 provided
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/basic_string.h:1283:7: note: std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>& std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::insert(std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::size_type, const _CharT*) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>, std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc> = std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::size_type = long unsigned int]
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/basic_string.h:1283:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::basic_string<char>::iterator {aka __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char> >}’ to ‘long unsigned int’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/basic_string.h:1306:7: note: std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>& std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::insert(std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::size_type, std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::size_type, _CharT) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>, std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc> = std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::size_type = long unsigned int]
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/basic_string.h:1306:7: note:   candidate expects 3 arguments, 2 provided
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/basic_string.h:1323:7: note: std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::iterator std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::insert(std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::iterator, _CharT) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>, std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char> >, typename _Alloc::rebind<_CharT>::other::pointer = char*]
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/basic_string.h:1323:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from ‘const Node’ to ‘char’
```

### Compiler/boost version

This is ubuntu 12.04

- gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3
- boost 1.46.

Having said that, I managed to reproduce my question on ubuntu 14.04 (gcc 4.8.2, boost 1.54)

Answer (score 2):

This reminds me a lot of this infamous limitation:

- [Spirit Qi attribute propagation issue with single-member struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19823413/spirit-qi-attribute-propagation-issue-with-single-member-struct/19824426#19824426)

However, I cannot make it click, and the usual workarounds don't seem to apply. You might report it on the `[spirit-general]` mailing list.

In the mean time, here's a phoenix workaround:

```
node_line = "  * " >> node [qi::_val=qi::_1];
```

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/afe8e4f548415386)**

Comment: [Another alternative](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f3095394fdcb849e) (not particularly pretty either).

Comment: According to the people on `[spirit-general]`, [I've found a bug](http://sourceforge.net/p/spirit/mailman/message/32970650/). They are working on it. In the mean time, your suggestions have unblocked me. In fact, my grammar has evolved to the point where it is so complex that spirit accepts it without complaints :-). Thanks for your support!

Comment: Ran into the same problem. As of Boost 1.6.1 still not fixed. :(

Comment: Also on Boost 1.64 with gcc 6.2 and MSVC 2017. And the developer said he already has a fix :-)