# Parsing unfinished text in boost::spirit::qi

Tags: c++, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

I want to parse a text which is read by using ifstream::read. The problem I'm facing is that the parser always return an expectation failure when reading an unfinished text. Here is my code for the parser.

```
template <typename It, typename Skipper= qi::space_type>
struct xmlparser: qi::grammar<It, std::string(), Skipper>{
    xmlparser(): xmlparser::base_type(xml_parser){
        using qi::lit;
        using qi::lexeme;
        using ascii::char_;
        using boost::phoenix::ref;
        using qi::debug;
        using boost::spirit::ascii::space;
        
        skipper= qi::char_("\t\r\n "); //qi::skip(skipper.alias())
        text = !lit('<') >> +(qi::char_ - qi::char_("<")) | lit('\'') | lit('\"');
        prolog = "<?" >> +(qi::char_ - '?') >> "?>";
        name = lexeme[qi::char_("a-zA-Z:_") >> *qi::char_("-a-zA-Z0-9:_")];
        attribute_value =
                    '"' > +(char_ - char_("<&\"")) > '"'
                    | '\'' > +(char_ - char_("<&'")) > '\''
                ;
        attribute = name[print_action("ATT")] >  '=' >  attribute_value[print_action("ATT VALUE")];
        start_tag %= '<' >> !lit('/') >> name >> *(attribute) >> !lit('/')>> '>';
        end_tag = "</" >> name >> '>';
        empty_tag =  '<' >> name >> *(attribute) >> "/>";
        xml_parser = 
            *(text/*[print_action("TEXT")]*/ 
                |start_tag[/*++ref(open_tag_count)*/print_action("OPEN")] 
                | end_tag[/*++ref(end_tag_count)*/print_action("END")] 
                | empty_tag[/*++ref(empty_tag_count)*/print_action("EMPTY")] 
                | prolog
                | skipper
            );
        }

        int get_empty_tag_count(){
            return empty_tag_count;
        }

        int get_open_tag_count(){
            return open_tag_count;
        }

        int get_end_tag_count(){
            return end_tag_count;
        }

        private:
            int open_tag_count= 0;
            int end_tag_count= 0;
            int empty_tag_count= 0;
            int text_count=0;

            qi::rule<It> skipper;
            qi::rule<It, std::string()> text;
            qi::rule<It, std::string()> prolog;
            qi::rule<It, std::string(),Skipper> name;
            qi::rule<It, std::string()> attribute_value;
            qi::rule<It, std::string(),Skipper> attribute;
            qi::rule<It, std::string(),Skipper> start_tag;
            qi::rule<It, std::string(),Skipper> end_tag;
            qi::rule<It, std::string(),Skipper> empty_tag;
            qi::rule<It, std::string(),Skipper> xml_parser;
};
```

I do not have any issues when I'm reading the text in using ifstream::getline since the text fed into the parser can be considered complete. However, when I'm reading the text by using ifstream::read, for example if it happened that the char[bufsize] stops at the middle of parsing the xml attribute and then it will return an expectation failure.

Example of unfinished text

```
</description>
<shipping>Will ship only within country, See description for charges</shipping>
<incategory category="category317"/>
<incategory category="categ
```

The function to read characters

```
char * buffer= new char[bufsize];
input_file.read(buffer,bufsize);
std::string bufstring(buffer);
if (extra != ""){
   bufstring = extra + bufstring;
   extra= "";
}
```

I wish to know if it is possible to return the fail parsed value and then added to the subsequent read from the buffer, since the subsequent read contains the continuation of the unfinished text. I have tried writing try and catch in order to put the failed to be parsed text to the next character read, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
    if (extra != ""){
        bufstring = extra + bufstring;
        extra= "";
    }
    // std::cout << bufstring << std::endl << std::endl;
    std::string::const_iterator iter= bufstring.begin();
    std::string::const_iterator end= bufstring.end();
    try{
        bool r= qi::phrase_parse(iter,end,xml_parser,qi::space);
        if (!r){
            std::cout << "Error found" << std::endl;
            extra = std::string(iter,end);
            std::cout << extra << std::endl;
            delete[] buffer;
            return;
        }
        if (iter!=end){
            extra = std::string(iter,end);
            // std::cout << extra << std::endl;
        }
    } catch (expectation_failure<char const*> const& e){
        std::cout<< std::string(iter,end) << std::endl;
        extra = std::string(iter,end);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't roll your own XML parser. XML libraries have stream parsers for this purpose. They work a bunch. I could go look for my xpathreader implementation if you're interested.

That said, maybe you're just trying learn Spirit Qi. Let's dig in.

Lots of small observations:

- `skipper` seems like a Very Bad name since you already have `Skipper` (the Qi feature)
- `qi::char_("\t\r\n ")` is very close to `qi::space` - if not identical.
- asserting `!lit('/')` is useless when you expect `name` anyways (which cannot legally start with '/').
- `char_ - char_(set)` is just `~char(set)`
- You do seem to have too many expectation points. Some of them make little sense. See e.g. [boost::spirit::qi Expectation Parser and parser grouping unexpected behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10378970/boostspiritqi-expectation-parser-and-parser-grouping-unexpected-behaviour/10390482#10390482)
- Attribute values can be empty
- Names are lexeme, so why declare a skipper? (see [Boost spirit skipper issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17072987/boost-spirit-skipper-issues/17073965#17073965))
- You didn't define `print_action`. Perhaps it is simply

  ```
   boost::phoenix::function print_action = [](auto&& arg) { std::cout << arg << "\n"; };
  ```

  Or a slightly more functional

  ```
   using namespace qi::labels;
   auto print_action = [](auto caption) {
       return std::cout << boost::phoenix::val(caption) << "[" << _1 << "] ";
   };
  ```

  Which mainly works because all rules ... expose a string attribute.
- About that.

  ```
   text = +~qi::char_("<") | '\'' | '\"';
  ```

  Has the net effect of accepting all text until an xml tag, or a single quote character. Even if you actually meant:

  ```
   text  = +(~qi::char_("<'\"") | '\'' | '"');
  ```

  it would be accepting all text until an xml tag but swallowing '' and '"' for... reasons?
- All rule expose a string attribute?! What are you parsing? What are you parsing *for*?

  The example

  ```xml
   </description>
   <shipping>Will ship only within country, See description for charges</shipping>
   <incategory category="category317"/>
   <incategory category="categ
  ```

  Suggest that you're merely tokenizing. If so, you probably want to expose the input sequences (`qi::raw`) and you wouldn't want to drop lexical items like the interpunction as you're doing now.
- Parsing from a forward-traversable container instead of input iterator would allow you to avoid copying the source sequences at all (either using a std::string_view or boost::iterator_range instead).
- Instead of a bespoke `print_action` consider using the builtin grammar debugging:

  ```
   BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES((skipper)(text)(prolog)(attribute)(start_tag)(
       end_tag)(empty_tag)(xml_parser)(name)(attribute_value))
  ```
- There's a conceptual thing on ordering rules in PEG grammars. PEG being greedy, left-to-right means that can reorder e.g.

  ```
   xml_parser =*(//
       text      [ print_action("TEXT")                            ] | //
       start_tag [ (++ref(open_tag_count), print_action("OPEN"))   ] |
       end_tag   [ (++ref(end_tag_count), print_action("END"))     ] |
       empty_tag [ (++ref(empty_tag_count), print_action("EMPTY")) ] |
       prolog | skipper);
  ```

  To be more like

  ```
   xml_parser =*(//
                 prolog |
       end_tag   [ (++ref(end_tag_count), print_action("END"))     ] |
       empty_tag [ (++ref(empty_tag_count), print_action("EMPTY")) ] |
       start_tag [ (++ref(open_tag_count), print_action("OPEN"))   ] |
       text      [ print_action("TEXT")                            ] | //
       skipper);
  ```

  *(Where skipper doesn't make sense unless you were to make it XML comment-aware)*

  Now you can drop the `!lit('<')` from the start of `text` as well.
- There's a problem with semantic actions ([Boost Spirit: "Semantic actions are evil"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8259440/boost-spirit-semantic-actions-are-evil)) and side-effects on container attributes ([Boost::Spirit doubles character when followed by a default value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70651941/boostspirit-doubles-character-when-followed-by-a-default-value/70652946#70652946)). The problem mainly being semantic actions. Also, I suggest that you would normally parse an "empty" tag (which isn't empty in many senses) as an open/close combo. This prevents all attributes being parsed doubly
- Updating parser members from semantic actions is also a surprise - violating the `const` contract of `.parse(...) const` because the semantic actions embed mutable references to member data.
- There's a lot of correctness issues with respect to valid XML. Your grammar doesn't even try to validate matching pairs of open/close tags. `prolog` is actual a processing instruction. I haven't checked that `?` cannot occur on its own before `?>`, have you?

  I don't think valid XML elements can start with `:`. There's no provision for namespaces, entity references, CDATA, PCDATA. And we'll not even open the can of worms that is XSD resolution/validation. This bullet will just be forgotten under the already mentioned "don't write your own XML parser". In fairness, many smaller XML libraries in the wild also have limitations like these.
- The expectation points. You need to decide what you want to happen. Do you want to parse only valid XML? Then you need strict expectations, as XML **requires** element tags as soon as `<` is encountered outside text/string context.

  However this is at odds with parsing. Maybe you can optionally "swallow" all expectations:

  ```
   qi::on_error(start,
                boost::phoenix::val(qi::error_handler_result::fail));
  ```

  Alternatively you could selectively deal with them when at end of input:

  ```
   qi::on_error<qi::fail>(
       attribute,
       boost::phoenix::if_(_3 != _2) // at end of input?
           [boost::phoenix::throw_(
                std::runtime_error("Expectation failure"))]
               .else_[std::cout << val("[EOF] Expecting ") << _4
                                << std::endl]);
  ```

### Putting Together A Demo

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8be46245db058195)**

```
//#define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG
#include <boost/phoenix.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi_match.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/support_istream_iterator.hpp>
#include <iomanip>
namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

template <typename It, typename Skipper = qi::space_type>
struct xmlparser : qi::grammar<It, std::string(), Skipper> {
    xmlparser() : xmlparser::base_type(start) {
        using boost::phoenix::ref;
        using boost::phoenix::val;
        using qi::lit;

        skipper         = qi::eps(false); // qi::char_("\t\r\n ");
        text            = +~qi::char_("<");
        prolog          = "<?" >> +(qi::char_ - '?') >> "?>";
        name            = qi::char_("a-zA-Z:_") >> *qi::char_("-a-zA-Z0-9:_");
        attribute_value = //
            '"' > *~qi::char_("<&\"") > '"' |
            '\'' > *~qi::char_("<&'") > '\'';

        //boost::phoenix::function print_action = [](auto&& arg) { std::cout << arg << "\n"; };
        using namespace qi::labels;
        auto print_action = [](auto caption) {
            return std::cout << boost::phoenix::val(caption) << "[" << _1 << "] ";
        };

#define INIT = // %=
        attribute INIT name[print_action("ATT")] > '=' >
            attribute_value[print_action("ATT VALUE")];
        start_tag INIT '<' >> !lit('/') >> name >> *attribute >> !lit('/') >> '>';
        end_tag   INIT "</" >> name >> '>';
        empty_tag INIT '<' >> name >> *attribute >> "/>";
        start INIT *(//
                      prolog |
            end_tag   [ (++ref(end_tag_count), print_action("END"))     ] |
            empty_tag [ (++ref(empty_tag_count), print_action("EMPTY")) ] |
            start_tag [ (++ref(open_tag_count), print_action("OPEN"))   ] |
            text      [ print_action("TEXT")                            ] |
            skipper);

        qi::on_error<qi::fail>(
            attribute,
            boost::phoenix::if_(_3 != _2) // at end of input?
                [boost::phoenix::throw_(
                     std::runtime_error("Expectation failure"))]
                    .else_[std::cout << val("[EOF] Expecting ") << _4
                                     << std::endl]);

        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES((skipper)(text)(prolog)(attribute)(start_tag)(
            end_tag)(empty_tag)(start)(name)(attribute_value))

    }

    int get_empty_tag_count() { return empty_tag_count; }
    int get_open_tag_count()  { return open_tag_count;  }
    int get_end_tag_count()   { return end_tag_count;   }

    void report(std::ostream& os) const {
        os << "open_tag_count  : " << open_tag_count  << std::endl;
        os << "end_tag_count   : " << end_tag_count   << std::endl;
        os << "empty_tag_count : " << empty_tag_count << std::endl;
        os << "text_count      : " << text_count      << std::endl;
    }

  private:

    int mutable open_tag_count  = 0;
    int mutable end_tag_count   = 0;
    int mutable empty_tag_count = 0;
    int mutable text_count      = 0;

    qi::rule<It, std::string(), Skipper> start, //
        attribute, start_tag, end_tag, empty_tag;

    qi::rule<It, std::string()> // lexemes
        prolog, text, name, attribute_value;
    qi::rule<It> skipper;
};

int main() {
    xmlparser<boost::spirit::istream_iterator> const p;
    std::istringstream iss(R"(
        </description>
        <shipping>Will ship only within country, See description for charges</shipping>
        <incategory category="category317"/>
        <incategory category="categ)");

    std::cout << iss.str() << "\n--------------------\n";

    for (std::string output;
         iss >> std::noskipws >> qi::phrase_match(p, qi::space, output);
         output.clear()) //
    {
        std::cout << "\n -- Output: " << std::quoted(output) << "\n";
    }

    p.report(std::cout << "\n");

    iss.clear();
    std::cout << "\n -- Remaining: " << iss.rdbuf() << std::endl;
}
```

Prints

```
        </description>
        <shipping>Will ship only within country, See description for charges</shipping>
        <incategory category="category317"/>
        <incategory category="categ
--------------------
END[description] OPEN[shipping] TEXT[Will ship only within country, See description for charges] END[shipping] ATT[category] ATT VALUE[category317] EMPTY[incategory] ATT[category] [EOF] Expecting """
ATT[category] [EOF] Expecting """

 -- Output: ""

open_tag_count  : 1
end_tag_count   : 2
empty_tag_count : 1
text_count      : 0

 -- Remaining:
```

And, if enabled, the debug output:

```xml
<start>
  <try>\n        </descripti</try>
  <prolog>
    <try></description>\n     </try>
    <fail/>
  </prolog>
  <end_tag>
    <try></description>\n     </try>
    <name>
      <try>description>\n       </try>
      <success>>\n        <shipping></success>
      <attributes>[[d, e, s, c, r, i, p, t, i, o, n]]</attributes>
    </name>
    <success>\n        <shipping>W</success>
    <attributes>[[d, e, s, c, r, i, p, t, i, o, n]]</attributes>
  </end_tag>
  <prolog>
    <try><shipping>Will ship </try>
    <fail/>
  </prolog>
  <end_tag>
    <try><shipping>Will ship </try>
    <fail/>
  </end_tag>
  <empty_tag>
    <try><shipping>Will ship </try>
    <name>
      <try>shipping>Will ship o</try>
      <success>>Will ship only with</success>
      <attributes>[[s, h, i, p, p, i, n, g]]</attributes>
    </name>
    <attribute>
      <try>>Will ship only with</try>
      <name>
        <try>>Will ship only with</try>
        <fail/>
      </name>
      <fail/>
    </attribute>
    <fail/>
  </empty_tag>
  <start_tag>
    <try><shipping>Will ship </try>
    <name>
      <try>shipping>Will ship o</try>
      <success>>Will ship only with</success>
      <attributes>[[s, h, i, p, p, i, n, g]]</attributes>
    </name>
    <attribute>
      <try>>Will ship only with</try>
      <name>
        <try>>Will ship only with</try>
        <fail/>
      </name>
      <fail/>
    </attribute>
    <success>Will ship only withi</success>
    <attributes>[[s, h, i, p, p, i, n, g]]</attributes>
  </start_tag>
  <prolog>
    <try>Will ship only withi</try>
    <fail/>
  </prolog>
  <end_tag>
    <try>Will ship only withi</try>
    <fail/>
  </end_tag>
  <empty_tag>
    <try>Will ship only withi</try>
    <fail/>
  </empty_tag>
  <start_tag>
    <try>Will ship only withi</try>
    <fail/>
  </start_tag>
  <text>
    <try>Will ship only withi</try>
    <success></shipping>\n        </success>
    <attributes>[[W, i, l, l,  , s, h, i, p,  , o, n, l, y,  , w, i, t, h, i, n,  , c, o, u, n, t, r, y, ,,  , S, e, e,  , d, e, s, c, r, i, p, t, i, o, n,  , f, o, r,  , c, h, a, r, g, e, s]]</attributes>
  </text>
  <prolog>
    <try></shipping>\n        </try>
    <fail/>
  </prolog>
  <end_tag>
    <try></shipping>\n        </try>
    <name>
      <try>shipping>\n        <i</try>
      <success>>\n        <incategor</success>
      <attributes>[[s, h, i, p, p, i, n, g]]</attributes>
    </name>
    <success>\n        <incategory</success>
    <attributes>[[s, h, i, p, p, i, n, g]]</attributes>
  </end_tag>
  <prolog>
    <try><incategory category</try>
    <fail/>
  </prolog>
  <end_tag>
    <try><incategory category</try>
    <fail/>
  </end_tag>
  <empty_tag>
    <try><incategory category</try>
    <name>
      <try>incategory category=</try>
      <success> category="category3</success>
      <attributes>[[i, n, c, a, t, e, g, o, r, y]]</attributes>
    </name>
    <attribute>
      <try> category="category3</try>
      <name>
        <try>category="category31</try>
        <success>="category317"/>\n   </success>
        <attributes>[[c, a, t, e, g, o, r, y]]</attributes>
      </name>
      <attribute_value>
        <try>"category317"/>\n    </try>
        <success>/>\n        <incatego</success>
        <attributes>[[c, a, t, e, g, o, r, y, 3, 1, 7]]</attributes>
      </attribute_value>
      <success>/>\n        <incatego</success>
      <attributes>[[i, n, c, a, t, e, g, o, r, y]]</attributes>
    </attribute>
    <attribute>
      <try>/>\n        <incatego</try>
      <name>
        <try>/>\n        <incatego</try>
        <fail/>
      </name>
      <fail/>
    </attribute>
    <success>\n        <incategory</success>
    <attributes>[[i, n, c, a, t, e, g, o, r, y]]</attributes>
  </empty_tag>
  <prolog>
    <try><incategory category</try>
    <fail/>
  </prolog>
  <end_tag>
    <try><incategory category</try>
    <fail/>
  </end_tag>
  <empty_tag>
    <try><incategory category</try>
    <name>
      <try>incategory category=</try>
      <success> category="categ</success>
      <attributes>[[i, n, c, a, t, e, g, o, r, y]]</attributes>
    </name>
    <attribute>
      <try> category="categ</try>
      <name>
        <try>category="categ</try>
        <success>="categ</success>
        <attributes>[[c, a, t, e, g, o, r, y]]</attributes>
      </name>
      <attribute_value>
        <try>"categ</try>
        <fail/>
      </attribute_value>
      <fail/>
    </attribute>
    <fail/>
  </empty_tag>
  <start_tag>
    <try><incategory category</try>
    <name>
      <try>incategory category=</try>
      <success> category="categ</success>
      <attributes>[[i, n, c, a, t, e, g, o, r, y]]</attributes>
    </name>
    <attribute>
      <try> category="categ</try>
      <name>
        <try>category="categ</try>
        <success>="categ</success>
        <attributes>[[c, a, t, e, g, o, r, y]]</attributes>
      </name>
      <attribute_value>
        <try>"categ</try>
        <fail/>
      </attribute_value>
      <fail/>
    </attribute>
    <fail/>
  </start_tag>
  <text>
    <try><incategory category</try>
    <fail/>
  </text>
  <skipper>
    <try><incategory category</try>
    <fail/>
  </skipper>
  <success><incategory category</success>
  <attributes>[[]]</attributes>
</start>
<start>
  <try></try>
  <prolog>
    <try></try>
    <fail/>
  </prolog>
  <end_tag>
    <try></try>
    <fail/>
  </end_tag>
  <empty_tag>
    <try></try>
    <fail/>
  </empty_tag>
  <start_tag>
    <try></try>
    <fail/>
  </start_tag>
  <text>
    <try></try>
    <fail/>
  </text>
  <skipper>
    <try></try>
    <fail/>
  </skipper>
  <success></success>
  <attributes>[[]]</attributes>
</start>
```

### PS

If you `#define INIT %=` you will see the problem with exposing `std::string()` on each string:

```
END[description] OPEN[descriptionshippingshipping] TEXT[descriptionshippingshippingWill ship only within country, See description for charges] END[descriptionshippingshippingWill ship only within country, See description for chargesshipping] ATT[descriptionshippingshippingWill ship only within country, See description for chargesshippingincategorycategory] ATT VALUE[descriptionshippingshippingWill ship only within country, See description for chargesshippingincategorycategorycategory317] EMPTY[descriptionshippingshippingWill ship only within country, See description for chargesshippingincategorycategorycategory317] ATT[descriptionshippingshippingWill ship only within country, See description for chargesshippingincategorycategorycategory317incategorycategory] [EOF] Expecting """
ATT[descriptionshippingshippingWill ship only within country, See description for chargesshippingincategorycategorycategory317incategorycategorycategincategorycategory] [EOF] Expecting """

 -- Output: "descriptionshippingshippingWill ship only within country, See description for chargesshippingincategorycategorycategory317incategorycategorycategincategorycategorycateg"
```

Comment: I forgot to add this example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72541294/parsing-unfinished-text-in-boostspiritqi It shows a "fuzzy" parser that knows how to detect faulty/incomplete input and gives suggestions to fix it, using identifier tables and expected tokens.

Comment: This is really a great help and I learnt a lot from this, Thank you @sehe. The link for other posts are very helpful as well. I want to build a multi-threaded xml parser where each thread will process a part of the xml, I plan to put validation on different thread later. Also, the link you gave in the comment is pointing to this post.

Comment: Fixing that link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47354226/how-to-provider-user-with-autocomplete-suggestions-for-given-boostspirit-gramm/47383910#47383910
- Before you make big plans about parallelizing XML parsing, I think it's really important to answer the main question: [_"What are you parsing? What are you parsing for?"_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72541294/parsing-unfinished-text-in-boostspiritqi/72548577?noredirect=1#comment128167093_72548577:~:text=a%20string%20attribute%3F!-,What%20are%20you%20parsing%3F%20What%20are%20you%20parsing%20for,-%3F).

Comment: I think the only answer that generically allows parallelizing is the one I gave: it looks like you're merely tokenizing. In that case be sure to not make it streaming, instead read the stream into a memory buffer and store tokens (e.g. string_views) into that buffer. This also avoids issues with the multi-pass iterator adaptor shared state (it buffers internally) which I don't think is thread-safe. Everything will be faster. Also, is there a reason you're not using Spirit X3 for this kind of task?

Comment: Hi, thank you again. I plan to parse XML and then create a tree from it, but before that i think i will create some object which is representation of the parsed values. At first, I thought I will be using qi::lex but turns out doing with just qi::grammar is enough and I just use Spirit v2 after that, maybe I should give spirit x3 a try.

Comment: I question whether parallelization the tokenization is going to give you any performance benefit. Ironically, if you're *only* doing that (lexing) then you might as well use **only** spirit lex (meaning, without Qi at all). But X3 is probably equivalent and 2 decades more modern. I'm tempted to say, it's how you plan on using your tools, not what tools. Don't expect to magically get useful parsers because you used a parser generator. Certainly not if you decide to use them in alternative ways :)