Is it possible to get the string that was parsed?
i got an working parser+AST based on Spirit that parses parameter initalization -
everything works fine
sadly there is some (old) database that wants parts of the AST as the original string (im on my way to replace that thing but want to make a step-by-step change)
(trivialized) example: a=10,b=30,c=A *B +10,d={1,A*4,3}*4
KeyValue-Rule = Identifier >> '=' >> Number|Expression

Expression is a complete Sub-AST with +-* and Numbers (in this trivialized example)
std::vector<KeyValue> Parameters;

the database wants the "values" of the parameters as string for c its A *B +10- at best with the exact string (with blanks etc.)
is that something Spirit can preserve (or the begin/end positions)?
the example above is a super trivialized version of my real parser/AST, expressions can be deeply leveld by () etc. - so its not a simple split by , thing - just to explain what i try to reach
something like: https://astexplorer.net/ - i need start/end-points of my logical AST parts in the string

It sounds like a contradiction. The string that was parsed was a=10,b=30,c=A *B +10, not A *B +10. If you want a specific sub-string, you'll need to tell us which substring.

my AST is (much complexer but typical) tree with all the parts key=value where value is itself an tree of simple number or an complex expression - now i need for example just the logical string (for example) that forms the value of key 'c'

I think you might be expecting too much from a parser. From the perspective of a parser, the value of c will be something like SYMBOL or VARIABLE or whatever your grammar specifies. Parsers don't execute your grammar, they only turn a string into an AST. Navigating the AST is your job.

Can't you "print" that subtree, or do you really need original data?

@MSalters parsers don't execute your grammar - i don't want my parser to execute anything, i hope my parser can additional to my AST return the begin/end positions of the coresspoding parts in the string

@Jarod42 - do you really need original data - would be best, there is a bunch of code after the database that is not under my control in any form - for example: expression changed = if the string changed in any form - etc. :)

@Jarod42 - do you really need original data - a trimmed version would be ok

Regardless you can do all that. See my answer :)

Yes. You could use semantic actions:
KeyValue-Rule = raw [ (Identifier >> '=' >> Number|Expression)[assign_ast] ][assign_raw_input_sequence];

You can use automatic attribute propagation in combination with semantic actions, using the %= rule initialization instead of regular = assignment.
You can also potentially automate things by using on_success "error" handlers. See some examples of that in my older answers: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A85371+qi+on_success
Imagine A Grammar
Coming up with the simplest possible grammar that doesn't have unary operators or operator precedence:
Live On Coliru
// #define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG
#include <boost/fusion/include/io.hpp>
#include <boost/phoenix.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <iomanip>
namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

// simple expression AST
namespace Ast {
    using Number     = double;
    using Variable   = std::string;
    using SimpleExpr = boost::variant<Number, Variable>;

    struct BinaryOp;
    struct Expr;
    using ExprV = boost::variant<SimpleExpr, boost::recursive_wrapper<BinaryOp>>;

    struct Expr : ExprV {
        using ExprV::ExprV;
        using ExprV::operator=;
    };

    struct BinaryOp {
        char op;
        Expr left, right;
    };

    using boost::fusion::operator<<;
} // namespace Ast

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Ast::BinaryOp, left, op, right)

// simple expression grammar
template <typename It> struct SimpleExprGrammar : qi::grammar<It, Ast::Expr()> {
    SimpleExprGrammar() : SimpleExprGrammar::base_type(start) {
        using namespace qi;

        start   = skip(space)[expr_ >> eoi];

        binary_ = simple_ >> char_("+*/-") >> expr_;
        expr_   = binary_ | simple_;
        simple_ = double_ | var_ | ('(' >> expr_ >> ')');
        var_    = +alpha;

        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES((expr_)(binary_)(binary_)(simple_)(var_))
    }

  private:
    qi::rule<It, Ast::Expr()> start;
    using Skipper = qi::space_type;
    qi::rule<It, Ast::Expr(), Skipper>     expr_;
    qi::rule<It, Ast::Expr(), Skipper>     simple_;
    qi::rule<It, Ast::BinaryOp(), Skipper> binary_;
    // lexemes
    qi::rule<It, Ast::Variable()>   var_;
};

int main() {
    SimpleExprGrammar<std::string_view::const_iterator> const p;

    for (std::string_view input : {
             "1 + 2",
             "1 + 2 * 3",
             "(1 + 2) * 3",
             "1 + 2 * (3 + 4)",
             "1 + 2 * (3 + 4) / 5",
             "1 + 2 * (3 + 4) / 5 - 6",
         }) {
        std::cout << " -- Parsing: " << quoted(input) << "\n";
        auto f = begin(input), l = end(input);

        if (Ast::Expr expr; qi::parse(f, l, p, expr))
            std::cout << "   -> " << expr << "\n";
        else
            std::cout << "   FAILED\n";
    }
}

Prints
 -- Parsing: "1 + 2"
   -> (1 + 2)
 -- Parsing: "1 + 2 * 3"
   -> (1 + (2 * 3))
 -- Parsing: "(1 + 2) * 3"
   -> ((1 + 2) * 3)
 -- Parsing: "1 + 2 * (3 + 4)"
   -> (1 + (2 * (3 + 4)))
 -- Parsing: "1 + 2 * (3 + 4) / 5"
   -> (1 + (2 * ((3 + 4) / 5)))
 -- Parsing: "1 + 2 * (3 + 4) / 5 - 6"
   -> (1 + (2 * ((3 + 4) / (5 - 6))))

Adding Source Annotation
Extend Expr:
struct Expr : ExprV {
    using ExprV::ExprV;
    using ExprV::operator=;

    std::string_view source;

    ExprV&       base() { return *this; }
    ExprV const& base() const { return *this; }
};

source will contain our source. Craft a semantic action to set the source from raw input iterators:
phx::function source_ = [](Ast::Expr& ast, std::string_view sv) { ast.source = sv; };
auto set_raw_         = source_(_val, phx::construct<std::string_view>(phx::begin(_1), phx::end(_1)));

Sprinkle semantic actions across the rules that should propagate both the parsed Ast and the source:
    expr_   = raw[(binary_[_val = _1] | simple_[_val = _1])][set_raw_];
    simple_ = raw[                         //
        double_[_val = _1]                 //
        | var_[_val = _1]                  //
        | ('(' >> expr_ >> ')')[_val = _1] //
    ][set_raw_];

As a bonus add an AnnoatedPrint visitor:
struct AnnotatedPrint {
    std::ostream&    os_;
    std::string_view input;
    std::string      indent = "";

    template <typename T> void operator()(T const& v) const { apply(v); }

  private:
    void apply(Ast::Expr const& e) const {
        std::cout << indent << "Source: " << quoted(e.source) << "\n";
        AnnotatedPrint{os_, input, indent + "  "}(e.base());
    }

    template <typename... Ts> void apply(boost::variant<Ts...> const& v) const {
        boost::apply_visitor(*this, v);
    }

    void apply(Ast::Number const& e) const { std::cout << indent << "Number: " << e << "\n"; }
    void apply(Ast::Variable const& e) const { std::cout << indent << "Variable: " << e << "\n"; }
    void apply(Ast::BinaryOp const& e) const {
        std::cout << indent << "BinaryOp: " << e.op << "\n";
        AnnotatedPrint{os_, input, indent + "  "}(e.left);
        AnnotatedPrint{os_, input, indent + "  "}(e.right);
    }
};

Now the output becomes Live On Coliru
 -- Parsing: "1 + 2"
   -> (1 + 2)
 -- AST: Source: "1 + 2"
 -- AST:   BinaryOp: +
 -- AST:     Source: "1"
 -- AST:       Number: 1
 -- AST:     Source: "2"
 -- AST:       Number: 2
 -- Parsing: "1 + 2 * 3"
   -> (1 + (2 * 3))
 -- AST: Source: "1 + 2 * 3"
 -- AST:   BinaryOp: +
 -- AST:     Source: "1"
 -- AST:       Number: 1
 -- AST:     Source: "2 * 3"
 -- AST:       BinaryOp: *
 -- AST:         Source: "2"
 -- AST:           Number: 2
 -- AST:         Source: "3"
 -- AST:           Number: 3
 -- Parsing: "(1 + 2) * 3"
   -> ((1 + 2) * 3)
 -- AST: Source: "(1 + 2) * 3"
 -- AST:   BinaryOp: *
 -- AST:     Source: "(1 + 2)"
 -- AST:       BinaryOp: +
 -- AST:         Source: "1"
 -- AST:           Number: 1
 -- AST:         Source: "2"
 -- AST:           Number: 2
 -- AST:     Source: "3"
 -- AST:       Number: 3
 -- Parsing: "1 + 2 * (3 + 4)"
   -> (1 + (2 * (3 + 4)))
 -- AST: Source: "1 + 2 * (3 + 4)"
 -- AST:   BinaryOp: +
 -- AST:     Source: "1"
 -- AST:       Number: 1
 -- AST:     Source: "2 * (3 + 4)"
 -- AST:       BinaryOp: *
 -- AST:         Source: "2"
 -- AST:           Number: 2
 -- AST:         Source: "(3 + 4)"
 -- AST:           BinaryOp: +
 -- AST:             Source: "3"
 -- AST:               Number: 3
 -- AST:             Source: "4"
 -- AST:               Number: 4
 -- Parsing: "1 + 2 * (3 + 4) / 5"
   -> (1 + (2 * ((3 + 4) / 5)))
 -- AST: Source: "1 + 2 * (3 + 4) / 5"
 -- AST:   BinaryOp: +
 -- AST:     Source: "1"
 -- AST:       Number: 1
 -- AST:     Source: "2 * (3 + 4) / 5"
 -- AST:       BinaryOp: *
 -- AST:         Source: "2"
 -- AST:           Number: 2
 -- AST:         Source: "(3 + 4) / 5"
 -- AST:           BinaryOp: /
 -- AST:             Source: "(3 + 4)"
 -- AST:               BinaryOp: +
 -- AST:                 Source: "3"
 -- AST:                   Number: 3
 -- AST:                 Source: "4"
 -- AST:                   Number: 4
 -- AST:             Source: "5"
 -- AST:               Number: 5
 -- Parsing: "1 + 2 * (3 + 4) / 5 - 6"
   -> (1 + (2 * ((3 + 4) / (5 - 6))))
 -- AST: Source: "1 + 2 * (3 + 4) / 5 - 6"
 -- AST:   BinaryOp: +
 -- AST:     Source: "1"
 -- AST:       Number: 1
 -- AST:     Source: "2 * (3 + 4) / 5 - 6"
 -- AST:       BinaryOp: *
 -- AST:         Source: "2"
 -- AST:           Number: 2
 -- AST:         Source: "(3 + 4) / 5 - 6"
 -- AST:           BinaryOp: /
 -- AST:             Source: "(3 + 4)"
 -- AST:               BinaryOp: +
 -- AST:                 Source: "3"
 -- AST:                   Number: 3
 -- AST:                 Source: "4"
 -- AST:                   Number: 4
 -- AST:             Source: "5 - 6"
 -- AST:               BinaryOp: -
 -- AST:                 Source: "5"
 -- AST:                   Number: 5
 -- AST:                 Source: "6"
 -- AST:                   Number: 6

Integrating It To The Question
Without further comment:
Live On Coliru
// #define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG
#include <boost/fusion/include/adapted.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/io.hpp>
#include <boost/phoenix.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <iomanip>
namespace qi  = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace phx = boost::phoenix;

// simple expression AST
namespace Ast {
    using Number     = double;
    using Variable   = std::string;
    using SimpleExpr = boost::variant<Number, Variable>;

    struct BinaryOp;
    struct Expr;
    using ExprV = boost::variant<SimpleExpr, boost::recursive_wrapper<BinaryOp>>;

    struct Expr : ExprV {
        using ExprV::ExprV;
        using ExprV::operator=;

        std::string_view source;

        ExprV&       base() { return *this; }
        ExprV const& base() const { return *this; }
    };

    struct BinaryOp {
        char op;
        Expr left, right;
    };

    using Def  = std::pair<Variable, Expr>;
    using Defs = std::map<Variable, Expr>;

    using boost::fusion::operator<<;
} // namespace Ast

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Ast::BinaryOp, left, op, right)

// simple expression grammar
template <typename It> struct DefParser : qi::grammar<It, Ast::Defs()> {
    DefParser() : DefParser::base_type(start) {
        using namespace qi;

        phx::function source_ = [](Ast::Expr& ast, std::string_view sv) { ast.source = sv; };
        auto set_raw_         = source_(_val, phx::construct<std::string_view>(phx::begin(_1), phx::end(_1)));

        start   = skip(space)[defs_ >> eoi];
        defs_   = def_ % ',';
        def_    = var_ >> '=' >> expr_;
        binary_ = simple_ >> char_("+*/-") >> expr_;
        expr_   = raw[(binary_[_val = _1] | simple_[_val = _1])][set_raw_];
        simple_ = raw[                         //
            double_[_val = _1]                 //
            | var_[_val = _1]                  //
            | ('(' >> expr_ >> ')')[_val = _1] //
        ][set_raw_];
        var_    = +alpha;

        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES((expr_)(binary_)(binary_)(simple_)(var_)(def_)(defs_))
    }

  private:
    qi::rule<It, Ast::Defs()> start;
    using Skipper = qi::space_type;
    qi::rule<It, Ast::Def(), Skipper>      def_;
    qi::rule<It, Ast::Defs(), Skipper>     defs_;
    qi::rule<It, Ast::Expr(), Skipper>     expr_;
    qi::rule<It, Ast::Expr(), Skipper>     simple_;
    qi::rule<It, Ast::BinaryOp(), Skipper> binary_;
    // lexemes
    qi::rule<It, Ast::Variable()>   var_;
};

int main() {
    using It = std::string_view::const_iterator;
    DefParser<It> const p;

    std::string_view input = "a=10,b=30,c=A *B +10,  PI = TAU / (((2)))";

    auto f = begin(input), l = end(input);
    if (Ast::Defs defs; qi::parse(f, l, p, defs)) {
        for (auto const& [v, e] : defs) {
            std::cout << "   -> " << v << " = " << e << "\n";
            auto pos = e.source.begin() - input.begin();
            std::cout << "Input: " << input << "\n";
            auto n = e.source.size() - 1;
            std::cout << "       " << std::setw(pos) << "" << "^" << std::string(n, '-') << "\n";
        }
    } else {
        std::cout << "FAILED\n";
    }
}

Prints
   -> PI = (TAU / 2)
Input: a=10,b=30,c=A *B +10,  PI = TAU / (((2)))
                                   ^------------
   -> a = 10
Input: a=10,b=30,c=A *B +10,  PI = TAU / (((2)))
         ^-
   -> b = 30
Input: a=10,b=30,c=A *B +10,  PI = TAU / (((2)))
              ^-
   -> c = (A * (B + 10))
Input: a=10,b=30,c=A *B +10,  PI = TAU / (((2)))
                   ^-------


PS. If you show your actual grammar/objective I might show a demo

Found the time to make a toy example myself. That should probably help :)

Aaand doing the same in X3: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c393fb7a971877c7

Found the time to make a toy example myself as a synonym for i made you an nearly full blown copyable solution for all your problems - and more :)

should i prefer X3 in the future?

based on your nice looking ^------- output - is it also possible to mark error points in parsing someway like that

latest VS2022/boost 1.86 does not compile your example - not cl/and clang-cl: clang-cl output: https://pastebin.com/BRD62Mkx

Clearly MSVC doesn't support the c++20 constructor for string_view. You can write it in any other way: c++20/c++17 version x3. The integrated example (Qi) all the way to c++11

Oh. I missed the X3 comment: I still recommend Qi. X3 is not as stable, especially around attribute propagation, which is at the core here. Qi is a little bit heavier and more verbose in spots, but I feel in control from A to Z

not a problem - i was a little confused because you sometimes switch between qi and x3 examples - and you forgot another comment behind :)

I figured it is obvious that you can do error reporting in a turing-complete language :) Regardless, I have many examples, search for expectation_failure or on_error. This one is the first hit on on_error and looks like a good starting point: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76466014/85371

I figured it is obvious that you can do error reporting in a turing-complete language - it  is :) - thanks for the example link

it compiles with clang-cl - but still not with VS2022: https://pastebin.com/Xb5y0mv3

"It" - what version is that? You could demonstrate it using an online compiler like RexTester or Compiler Explorer?

this version: https://pastebin.com/rMPmcLWE - sadly RexTester allows C++/msvc only for patrons and the Compiler Explorer got problems using boost in MSVC scenario (open bug)

Seems to be MSVC once again being challenged with conformance. Here's a version that avoids the template expressions tripping it up: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9e55838b115f0039 (RexTester completely chokes on MSVC 19.00.23506/Boost160 https://rextester.com/FSLSP73065)

Yay. I booted into windows for the first time in forever, installed VS2022 Community, Boost 1.86.0 headers and ran the code: https://imgur.com/a/kAM1nLz - also keeping the Boost string_view implementation: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/931714e7c94e8e7f

thanks - im using both windows and linux and i always need to test both systems/compiler - it much bettern then 10 years ago

Yeah. I'm surprised their own front-end still has issues with common code like this. Looks like they pick up the wrong operator& (unlikely, if anything ADL was /overzealous/ before 2-phase name lookup was corrected) or they completely wrongly apply the lvalue diagnostic to user-defined operator&. Anyways, happy it works now
