# Parse MemoryMapped files using Spirit quoted and normal

Tags: c++, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

in according to [the answer from sehe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10289985/parse-quoted-strings-with-boostspirit/10294577#10294577) i want to parse quoted and normal content from a memory mapped file, **as fast as possible**.

The actual Parser looks like:

```
namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

using MatrixType =  std::vector<std::vector<boost::string_ref>>;
template<typename It>
struct parser : qi::grammar<It,  MatrixType(), qi::blank_type,  qi::locals<char> >
{
    parser()
    : parser::base_type( table, "parser" )
{
    using namespace boost::phoenix;
    using namespace qi;

    delimiter = ',';
    quoted =
        omit [ char_("'\"") [_a = _1] ]
        >> raw [ *(char_ - char_(_a)) ] [  _val = construct<boost::string_ref>(begin(_1), size(_1)) ]
        >> lit(_a);
     unquoted = raw[ *(char_ - (eol | delimiter) ) ] [ _val = construct<boost::string_ref>(begin(_1), size(_1))]; //raw [ *(char_ - char_("\"',")) ] [  _val = construct<boost::string_ref>(begin(_1), size(_1)) ];

    any_string = quoted | unquoted;
    line  = any_string  % delimiter;
    table = line % eol;

}

qi::rule<It, boost::string_ref() ,qi::locals<char> , qi::blank_type> any_string;
qi::rule<It, boost::string_ref() ,qi::locals<char> , qi::blank_type> quoted;
qi::rule<It, boost::string_ref() ,qi::locals<char> , qi::blank_type> unquoted;
qi::rule<It> delimiter;
 qi::rule<It, std::vector<boost::string_ref>(), qi::blank_type> line;
qi::rule<It, MatrixType(), qi::blank_type, qi::locals<char>> table;

};
```

example Inputfile:

```
"a","b",   "c", "d,e,f"
"a", -1, abc, 0.1
```

The actual parser add one , not existing empty line. There is no "\n" at the end of the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that end-of-line and end-of-input are implicitly delimiters.

Since unquoted fields are allowed to be "empty" (zero-length), this will just parse one final line containing a single empty field.

I'd suggest checking for end-of-input specifically:

```
row = !eoi >> any_string % delimiter;
```

Rows are rejected if there's nothing at all to be read. In order to be lenient and allow trailing empty lines, you could "eat" those:

```
table = row % eol >> *eol;
```

Finally, if you also want to "eat" empty lines in between table rows, simply add the repeat (kleene plus):

```
table = row % +eol >> *eol;
```

Demo **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2089308d3a99c360)</kbd>**

```
#define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG
#include <boost/utility/string_ref.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

using MatrixType = std::vector<std::vector<boost::string_ref>>;

template<typename It>
struct parser : qi::grammar<It, MatrixType(), qi::blank_type >
{
    parser() : parser::base_type(table, "parser")
    {
        namespace px = boost::phoenix;
        using namespace qi;

        delimiter = ',';
        quoted    =
               char_("'\"") [_a = _1] 
            >> raw [ *(char_ - char_(_a)) ] [ _val = px::construct<boost::string_ref>(px::begin(_1), px::size(_1)) ]
            >> lit(_a);
        unquoted   = raw[ *(char_ - (eol | delimiter) ) ] [ _val = px::construct<boost::string_ref>(px::begin(_1), px::size(_1))]; 

        any_string = quoted | unquoted;
        row        = !eoi >> any_string % delimiter;
        table      = row % +eol >> *eol;

        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES((delimiter)(quoted)(unquoted)(any_string)(row)(table))
    }

  private:
    qi::rule<It, MatrixType(),             qi::blank_type> table;
    qi::rule<It, MatrixType::value_type(), qi::blank_type> row;

    // lexemes
    qi::rule<It, boost::string_ref(), qi::locals<char> > quoted;
    qi::rule<It, boost::string_ref()> any_string, unquoted;
    qi::rule<It> delimiter;
};

#include <fstream>
#include <boost/iostreams/device/mapped_file.hpp>

int main() {
    using It = const char*;

    boost::iostreams::mapped_file_source source("input.txt");
    It first = source.begin();
    It last  = source.end();

    parser<It> grammar;
    MatrixType data;
    bool ok = qi::phrase_parse(first, last, grammar, qi::blank, data);

    if (ok) {
        std::cout << "Parsed: \n";
        for (auto& row : data)
        {
            for (auto& cell : row)
                std::cout << cell << "|";
            std::cout << "\n";
        }
    } else
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to parse\n";
    }

    if (first != last) {
        std::cout << "Remaining input unparsed: '" << std::string(first, last) << "'\n";
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
Parsed: 
a|b|c|d,e,f|
a|-1|abc|0.1|
a||abc|0.1|
```

Comment: Here's the [live-stream recording](https://www.livecoding.tv/video/avoid-empty-trailing-lines-in-spirit-grammars/) in case you're interested. ([experiment](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/10?m=24182469#24182469))