# How to ignore delimiter when it commented or quoted

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit

I write a parser to find string concatenation expressions. I have a range of strings which are enclosed by parentheses, originated mainly from a function call.

For example, `("one"+"two"+"three") -> ("one"|"two"|"three")` is a simple case and I can handle it.

A more difficult case is `(null, "one"+"two"+"three", null) -> (null, "one"|"two"|"three", null)`, but I'm able parse it with `boost::tokenizer`.

`(null, "one"+"two"+"three,four", 1 /* third parameter can be: 1, 2, 3 */)`, in such a difficult example I suggest parsing with `boost::spirit` but I need help in writing some rules for it.

**Later:**

Seems like `escaped_list_separator`from the `boost::tokenizer` is what I need.
But I have one problem with it:

```
   using namespace std;
   using namespace boost;
   string s = "Field 1,\"putting quotes around fields, allows commas\",Field 3";
   tokenizer<escaped_list_separator<char> > tok(s,escaped_list_separator<char>("", ",", "\""));
   for(tokenizer<escaped_list_separator<char> >::iterator beg=tok.begin(); beg!=tok.end();++beg){
       cout <<"~~~"<< *beg << "\n";
   }
```

removes `"` for me. It is possible to keep quotes in output like this

```
Field 1
"putting quotes around fields, allows commas"
Field 3
```

Comment: There are more than enough answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120140/csv-parser-in-c

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you can use `operator-` with charset matches:

```
   rule = '"' >> (char_ - '"') >> '"';
```

Also look at `operator ~` to invert a charset.

If you are interested in escaping quotes inside quotes as well, and perhaps commenting styles at the same time, I recommend having a look at my answer here:

- [How to make my split work only on one real line and be capable to skip quoted parts of string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7436481/how-to-make-my-split-work-only-on-one-real-line-and-be-capable-to-skeep-quoted-p/7462539#7462539)

Showing (partially) quoted cells in CSV files, including escaped quotes inside strings.

Other items of interest:

- [Cross-platform way to get line number of an INI file where given option was found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8358975/cross-platform-way-to-get-line-number-of-an-ini-file-where-given-option-was-foun/8365427#8365427)

  Ignoring stuff in comments and escaping comment delimiters
- [Parse quoted strings with boost::spirit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10289985/parse-quoted-strings-with-boostspirit/10294577#10294577)

  Showing various styles of quoted string parsing, including embedded escaped quotes.