# Parse tab delimited file with Boost.Spirit where entries may contain whitespace in

Tags: c++, parsing, boost, boost-spirit, csv

I want to parse a tab delimited file using Boost.Spirit (Qi). My file looks something like this:

```
John Doe\tAge 23\tMember
Jane Doe\tAge 25\tMember
...
```

Is it possible to parse this with a *skip parser*? The problem I have right now is, that `boost::spirit::ascii:space` also skips the whitespace within the name of the person. How would the `phrase_parse(...)` call look like?

I am also using the Boost.Fusion tuples for convient storing of the results in a struct:

```
struct Person
{
    string name;
    int age;
    string status;
};
```

This seems to work for the `name`:

```
String %= lexeme[+(char_-'\t')];
```

It matches everything char that is not a tab. It is then used as part of the bigger rule:

```
Start %= Name >> Age >> Status;
```

Answer (score 0):

> Q. Is it possible to parse this with a skip parser?

A. No, it's not possible to parse anything with the skip parser. Skippers achieve the opposite: they disregard certain input information.

However, what you seem to be looking for something like this hack: (I don't recommend it)

- [Read empty values with boost::spirit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28931487/read-empty-values-with-boostspirit/28933565#28933565)

Now, you could look at my other answers for proper ways to parse CSV/TSV dealing with embedded whitespace, quoted values, escaped quotes etc. (I believe one even shows line-continuation characters)

- [How to parse csv using boost::spirit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18365463/how-to-parse-csv-using-boostspirit/18366335#18366335)
- [Parse quoted strings with boost::spirit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10289985/parse-quoted-strings-with-boostspirit/10294577#10294577)
- [How to make my split work only on one real line and be capable to skip quoted parts of string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7436481/how-to-make-my-split-work-only-on-one-real-line-and-be-capable-to-skeep-quoted-p/7462539#7462539)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! My understanding so far was, that I would need a skip parser, that ignores tabs and newlines. This would leave me with only the parts that I am interested in, which could be parsed by rules. Is there a Skipper which does this already, or do I need to roll my own?