# C++ String splitting but escaping all delimiters in quotations

Tags: c++, regex, csv, stl

Using C++, I would like to split the rows of a string (CSV file in this case) where some of the fields may contain delimiters that are escaped (using "") and should be seen as literals. I have looked at the various questions already posed by have not found a direct answer to my problem.

Example of CSV file data:

```
Header1,Header2,Header3,Header4,Header5
Hello,",,,","world","!,,!,",","
```

Desired string vector after splitting:

```
["Hello"],[",,,"],["world"],["!,,!,"],[","]
```

Note: The CSV is only valid if the number of data columns equal the number of header columns.

Would prefer a non-boost / third-party solution. Efficiency is not a priority.

**EDIT:**
Code below implementing regex from @ClasG at least satisfies the scenario above. I am drafting fringe test cases but would love to hear when / where it breaks down...

```
std::string s = "Hello,\",,,\",\"world\",\"!,,!,\",\",\"\"";    
std::string rx_string = "(\"[^\"]*\"|[^,]*)(?:,|$)";
regex e(rx_string);
std::regex_iterator<std::string::iterator> rit ( s.begin(), s.end(), e );
std::regex_iterator<std::string::iterator> rend;

while (rit!=rend) 
{
    std::cout << rit->str() << std::endl;
    ++rit;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120140/how-can-i-read-and-parse-csv-files-in-c

Comment: There is no standard csv library. Why are you so keen to avoid a third-party solution?

Comment: @BoBTFish Will happily consider third-party based answers. Just stating what will be ideal for this use-case.

Comment: Use an embarassingly simple state machine to parse each char. Done. No 3rd party libaries.

Comment: csv looks simple but can contain a lot of corner cases. You should first read what [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) says about it. IMHO, you should first specify *exactly* what you need (separators in fields, quote char in fields, end of line in fields, etc.), build a range of test cases, and then implement it *by hand* and test your implementation. Alternatively, pick up a csv library, control if its specs meet your requirement, test it and use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a complete (c++) solution, but a regex that might nudge you in the right direction.

A regex like

```
("[^"]*"|[^,]*)(?:,|$)
```

will match the individual columns. (Note that it doesn't handle escaped quotes.)

[See it here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/1WrbY7/2).

Comment: Hmm, I won't do it, but did you test your regex on all possible csv corner cases, mainly: separators, new lines or quote chars in fields?

Comment: I'm not sure if the supported languages' regex matches to c++ at all but +1 for the cool resource link.

Comment: @SergeBallesta As mentioned - "Not a complete solution". It does however handle the example given, and I assume that's representative of the cases possible.

Comment: What flavor of c++ are you using then? 11, 14...?

Comment: @ClasG VS2012 so can use at least c++11. Will try a regex test app. Are you saying that the php regex at regex101 will translate directly? (Not a c++ regex expert at all but eager to learn)

Comment: The regex I've given is very basic. I don't know of any regex flavor that don't support it. (Well, the old `CAtlRegEx` would need some tweaking of it ;)

Comment: @ClasG Thanks. Seems like a great start at least :)

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer, but it's too long to put as a comment IMHO.

CSV is one of those seemingly-simple-but-actually-quite-fiendish storage formats.

The droid you're looking for is Boost.Spirit.

The Spirit Master's name (on stack overflow) is @sehe.

See his answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18366335/2015579

Please credit sehe, not me.

Comment: Will need more expertise to appreciate his implementation. But thanks.

Comment: @Willeman boost.sprit generates a parser state machine for you. It's complicated as hell until you get the hang of it.