# CSV like Parse ( whitespace delimiter and boost )

Tags: c++, boost

i want to parse a CSV-like file, line with boost.
There are many different methods like split, tokenise, spirit, regex...

A parsing line could look like: `"abc" "def"       "hij \"hgfd\" "`
and the result should look like:

```
"abc"
"def"
"hij \"hgfd\" "
```

I thought that using boost's tokenises with the escaped_list_separator would be a great idea but it is not possible to split on whitespace delimiter, isnt it ?

Comment: CSV (and similar file formats) are *deceptively* easy to parse. I say deceptively, because there are many corner-cases that will cause problems, like you have noticed. To solve your problem you need a stateful parser, you need to keep a state telling you what kind of token you are parsing. For example, if the state says you're in a string you should read spaces and add them to the string instead of treating them as field separators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick and dirty to match just what you described using Spirit (multiple lines into a vector>):

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c8d58ff17ebe3385)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi_match.hpp>
namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

int main() {
    std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> csv_data;

    if (std::cin 
            >> std::noskipws 
            >> qi::phrase_match(*qi::lexeme['"' >> *('\\' >> qi::char_ | ~qi::char_("\r\n\"")) >> '"'] % qi::eol, qi::blank, csv_data))
    {
        std::cout << "Parse succeeded: " << csv_data.size() << "\n";
        for(auto& row: csv_data) {
            for(auto& c: row) std::cout << c << '|';
            std::cout << "\n";
        }
    } else {
        std::cout << "Parse failed\n";
    }
}
```

The example printing:

```
Parse succeeded: 3
abc|def|hij "hgfd" |
qwehjr|aweqwejkl||
```

> For a background on parsing (optionally) quoted delimited fields, including different quoting characters (`'`, `"`), see here:
>
> - [Parse quoted strings with boost::spirit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10289985/parse-quoted-strings-with-boostspirit/10294577#10294577)
>
> For a *very, very, very* complete example complete with support for *partially quoted* values and a
>
> ```
> splitInto(input, output, ' ');
> ```
>
> method that takes 'arbitrary' output containers and delimiter expressions, see here:
>
> - [How to make my split work only on one real line and be capable to skip quoted parts of string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7436481/how-to-make-my-split-work-only-on-one-real-line-and-be-capable-to-skeep-quoted-p/7462539#7462539)

Comment: wow that is really expressive !!! elegant !!! and flexible !!! amazing! could you write something about the techniques used in / for this example to learn ? im really new to THIS c++ and boost. Normally i mixes ansi c with a little bit of c++ ( old standard ) is there a book available ?

Comment: Thanks (I just noticed I had forgotten to copy the sample into the answer directly)

Comment: @Roby books: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list - There's not really a boost book (but see http://theboostcpplibraries.com/)