# boost::spirit::qi preserving white space

Tags: c++, boost-spirit-qi

I am using this code to parse "k1=v1;k2=v2;k3=v3;kn=vn" string into a map.

```
    qi::phrase_parse(
      begin,end,
      *(*~qi::char_('=') >> '=' >> *~qi::char_(';') >> -qi::lit(';')),
      qi::ascii::space, dict);
```

The above code would remove space chars, e.g. "some_key=1 2 3" becomes some_key -> 123

I can't figure out how to remove or what to replace with the fourth parameter: qi::ascii::space

Bacically, I want to preserve the original string (key and value) after splitting by '='.

I do not have much experience/knowledge with spirit. It does require investing time to learn.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Boost spirit skipper issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17072987/boost-spirit-skipper-issues)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want no skipper, simply use `qi::parse` instead of `qi::phrase_parse`:

```
qi::parse(
  begin,end,
  *(*~qi::char_(";=") >> '=' >> *~qi::char_(';') >> -qi::lit(';')),
  dict);
```

However, you likely DO want to selectively skip whitespace. The easiest way is usually to have a general skipper, and then mark the lexeme areas (where you don't allow the skipper):

```
qi::phrase_parse(
  begin, end,
  *(qi::lexeme[+(qi::graph - '=')]
     >> '='
     >> qi::lexeme[*~qi::char_(';')] >> (qi::eoi|';')),
  qi::ascii::space, dict);
```

The [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17072987/boost-spirit-skipper-issues) does give more techniques/backgrounds on how to work with skippers in Qi

### DEMO TIME

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/943c3c21528aa379)**

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/std_pair.hpp>
#include <map>
#include <iomanip>
namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

int main() {
    for (std::string const& input : { 
            R"()",
            R"(foo=bar)",
            R"(foo=bar;)",
            R"( foo = bar ; )",
            R"( foo = bar ;
foo 
= qux; baz =

    quux 
corge grault
 thud

; x=)",
            // failing:
            R"(;foo = bar;)",
        })
    {
        std::cout << "-------------------------\n";
        auto f=begin(input), l=end(input);

        std::multimap<std::string, std::string> dict;

        bool ok = qi::phrase_parse(f, l,
          (qi::lexeme[+(qi::graph - '=' - ';')]
             >> '='
             >> qi::lexeme[*~qi::char_(';')]
          ) % ';',
          qi::space,
          dict);

        if (ok) {
            std::cout << "Parsed " << dict.size() << " elements:\n";
            for (auto& [k,v]: dict) {
                std::cout << " - " << std::quoted(k) << " -> " << std::quoted(v) << "\n";
            }
        } else {
            std::cout << "Parse failed\n";
        }

        if (f!=l) {
            std::cout << "Remaining input: " << std::quoted(std::string(f,l)) << "\n";
        }
    }

}
```

Prints

```
-------------------------
Parse failed
-------------------------
Parsed 1 elements:
 - "foo" -> "bar"
-------------------------
Parsed 1 elements:
 - "foo" -> "bar"
Remaining input: ";"
-------------------------
Parsed 1 elements:
 - "foo" -> "bar "
Remaining input: "; "
-------------------------
Parsed 4 elements:
 - "baz" -> "quux 
corge grault
 thud

"
 - "foo" -> "bar "
 - "foo" -> "qux"
 - "x" -> ""
-------------------------
Parse failed
Remaining input: ";foo = bar;"
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. This is really good. I really have no idea about this Expression construct and I will not, unless I start reading spirit tutorial from beginning. But I do understand what it does. From what I see, for the KEY leading left and right whitespace is removed. For the VAL leading left is removed and all other (middle, right) are preserved. I will use it for my solution. It makes mores sense than just using parse()

Comment: How do I adjust the expression to skip both, leading and trailing white space chars? I think that would make sense, only preserve spaces inside a value string.

Comment: This feels a bit like cheating, but is probably the most elegant way to achieve this, leveraging the skipper itself: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/57775008b2b357ce.

Comment: Thanks sehe. Why does it feels like cheating?

Comment: Because `qi::raw[]` returns the row input, which may not always be what you want (think e.g. supporting character escapes). See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7436481/how-to-make-my-split-work-only-on-one-real-line-and-be-capable-to-skip-quoted-pa/7462539#7462539

Comment: I am a bit confused. In the answer you give this expression:

*(qi::lexeme[+(qi::graph - '=')] >> '='>> qi::lexeme[*~qi::char_(';')] >> (qi::eoi|';'))

In the DEMO it is:
(qi::lexeme[+(qi::graph - '=' - ';')]  >> '='  >> qi::lexeme[*~qi::char_(';')] ) % ';'

The output seems to be the same.

Comment: @M.K.Good spot. I decided that excluding ';' made sense while adding more test cases. I ended up not including all the edge cases because they'd only raise questions about requirements, and they weren't relevant to the answer. You can obviously change the grammar as required :)